# Lambda or functools.partial for deferred function evaluation?

Tags: python, lambda, deferred-loading

Let's say we have a basic function:

```
def basic(arg):
    print arg
```

We need to defer the evaluation of this function in another function. I am thinking about 2 possible ways:

1. Using lambdas:

   ```
   def another(arg):
       return lambda: basic(arg)
   ```
2. Using functools.partial

   ```
   from functools import partial
       def another(arg):
           return partial(basic, arg)
   ```

Which of these approaches is preferred and why? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I assume you mean partial(basic, arg)?

Comment: That's right, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambdas don't store data which is not in its argument. This could lead to strange behaviors:

```
def lambdas(*args):
    for arg in args:
        yield lambda: str(arg)

one, two, three, four = lambdas(1, 2, 3, 4)
print one(), two(), three(), four()
```

#### Expected output

```
1 2 3 4
```

#### Output

```
4 4 4 4
```

This happens because the lambda didn't store the `arg` value and it went through all the elements of `args`, so now `arg` is always `4`.

The preferred way is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), where you are forced to store the arguments:

```
from functools import partial

def partials(*args):
    for arg in args:
        yield partial(str, arg)

one, two, three, four = partials(1, 2, 3, 4)
print one(), two(), three(), four()
```

#### Expected output

```
1 2 3 4
```

#### Output

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: In general, the concerns you raise over the late-binding nature of Python's `lambda`s are valid, although I don't think they're exactly applicable to the specific use case (deferred function evaluation) presented by this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this mostly comes down to personal taste, although `functools.partial` [is believed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653777/2970862) to be somewhat faster than an equivalent `lambda`. I prefer to use `functools.partial` in such situations as in my opinion it makes sense to indicate that we're dealing with a simple partial function application and not a full-blown closure.