# What is in a Python closure and what are the caveats for people used to OCaml?

Tags: python, closures, ocaml, lexical-closures

This is a sort of a follow-up on [an old answer to a question about the necessity of functools.partial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25822021/6221949) : while that answer very clearly explains the phenomenon and the basic reason for it, there are still some unclear points to me.

To recap, the following Python code

```
myfuns = [lambda arg: str(arg) + str(clo) for clo in range(4)]
try :
    clo
except NameError :
    print("there is no clo")
for arg in range(4) :
    print(myfuns[arg](arg), end=", ")
```

gives `03, 13, 23, 33,` , while the similar OCaml code

```
let myfuns = Array.map (fun clo -> fun arg -> (string_of_int arg) ^ (string_of_int clo)) [|0;1;2;3|];;
(* there is obviously no clo variable here *)
for arg = 0 to 3 do
  print_string (myfuns.(arg) arg); print_string ", "
done;;
```

gives `00, 11, 22, 33,` .

I understand this is related to a different notion of closure applied to `lambda arg: str(arg) + str(clo)` and its correspondent `fun arg -> (string_of_int arg) ^ (string_of_int clo)`.

In OCaml, the closure maps the identifier `clo` to the value of the variable `clo` in the outer scope at the time of creation of the closure. In Python, the closure somehow contains the variable `clo` per se, which explains that it gets affected by the incrementation caused by the `for` generator.

**Is this correct ?**

**How is this done ?** The `clo` variable does not exist in the global scope, as evidenced by my `try`/`except` construct. Generally, I would assume that the variable of a generator is local to it and so does not survive it. So, again, where is `clo` ? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414638/6221949) gives insight about `__closure__` but I still do not completely grasp how it manages to refer to the `clo` variable per se during the generation.

Also, beside this strange behaviour (for people used to statically binding languages), **are there other caveats one should be aware of ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python creates a closure is collects all free variables into a tuple of [cells](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/cell.html). Since each cell is mutable, and Python passes a reference to the cell into the closure, you will see the last value of the induction variable in your loop. Let's look underneath the hood, here is our function, with `i` occurring free in our lambda expression,

```
def make_closures():
    return [lambda x: str(x) + str(i) for i in range(4)]
```

and here is the [disassembly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) of this function

```
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                21 (to 37)
             16 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)
             19 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (i)
             22 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             25 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <lambda>)
             28 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             31 LIST_APPEND              2
             34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   37 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can see that `STORE_DEREF` on `16` takes a normal integer value from the top of the stack (TOS) and stores it with the `STORE_DEREF` in a cell. The next three commands prepare the closure structure on the stack, and finally `MAKE_CLOSURE` packs everything into the closure, which is represented as a tuple (in our case 1-tuple) of cells,

```
 >>> fs = make_closures()
 >>> fs[0].__closure__
 (<cell at 0x7ff688624f30: int object at 0xf72128>,)
```

so it is a tuple with a cell containing an int,

```
 >>> fs[0].__closure__[0]
 <cell at 0x7ff688624f30: int object at 0xf72128>

 >>> type(fs[0].__closure__[0])
 cell
```

The crucial to the understanding point here, is that free variables are shared by all closures,

```
>>> fs[0].__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f1d63f08b40: int object at 0xf16128>,)

>>> fs[1].__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f1d63f08b40: int object at 0xf16128>,)
```

As each cell is a reference to a local variable in the enclosing function scope, indeed, we can find the `i` variable in the `make_closures` function, in the `cellvars` attribute,

```
>>> make_closures.func_code.co_cellvars
('i',)
```

Therefore, we have a little bit<sup>?</sup> surprising effect of an integer value being passed by reference and becoming mutable. The main surprise in Python is the way how variables are packed and that the for loop is not having its own scope.

To be fair, you can achieve the same result in OCaml if you manually create a reference and capture it in a closure.  e.g.,

```
let make_closures () =
  let arg = ref 0 in
  let fs = Array.init 4 (fun _ -> fun _ -> assert false) in
  for i = 0 to 3 do
    fs.(i) <- (fun x -> string_of_int x ^ string_of_int !arg);
    incr arg
  done;
  fs
```

so that

```
let fs = make_closures ()
fs.(1) 1;;
- : string = "14"
```

## Historical References

Both OCaml and Python are influenced by Lisp and both imply the same technique for implementing closures. Surprisingly with different results, but not due to different interpretations of lexical scoping or closure environment but due to different object(data) models of the two languages.

The OCaml data model is not only simpler to understand but is also well defined by the rigorous type system. Python, due to its dynamic structure, leaves a lot of freedom in the interpretation of objects and their representation. Therefore, in Python, they decided to make variables bound in the lexical context of a closure [mutable by default](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/039214.html) (even if they are integers). See also the [PEP-227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) for more context.

Comment: Do you have a reference about this part of the Python semantics that does not involve the C interface or the bytecode implementation and/or the reason/advantages of doing so ? Also, after thinking about it I find that a more correct translation of the OCaml code into Python would be ``myfuns = [(lambda x : lambda arg : str(arg)+str(x))(clo) for clo in range(4)]``. This is not an eta-conversion because ``x`` is free in ``lambda arg : str(arg)+str(x)``.

Comment: Python is inherently defined by the implementation, so we can talk only about CPython. The rest could be different, but all other implementations are trying to follow CPython. I've added a couple of references, but it is hard to get more, since it was mostly implemented mostly before the Internet era.

Comment: "Python is a pass-by-reference language" Python is a solely pass-by-value language, in the same way that Java is a solely pass-by-value language. Python closures, however, capture variables by reference.

Comment: I don't want to be dragged into the pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference terminology holy war (especially, since Python is neither, nor this separation actually matters nowdays), so I just removed this ambiguous notion from the posting.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that python has variables and ocaml has bindings and currying.

```
Python:
myfuns = [lambda arg: str(arg) + str(clo) for clo in range(4)]
```

The `for` loop creates a variable `clo` and assigns the values 0, 1, 2, 3 to it for each iteration. The lambda binds the variable so it can later call `str(clo)`. But since the loop last assigned 3 to `clo` all the lambdas append the same string.

```
Ocaml:
let myfuns = Array.map (fun clo -> fun arg -> (string_of_int arg) ^ (string_of_int clo)) [|0;1;2;3|];;
```

Here you call Array.map with the array `[|0;1;2;3|]`. This will evaluate the `fun clo -> ...` binding `clo` to each value in the array in turn. Each time the binding will be different so the `string_of_int clo` turns out different too.

While not the only difference this partial evaluation saves the day in python too. If you write your code like this:

```
Python:
def make_lambda(clo):
    return lambda arg: str(arg) + str(clo)
myfuns = [make_lambda(clo) for clo in range(4)]
```

The evaluation of make_lambda causes the `clo` in the lambda to be bound to the value of the make_lambda argument, not the variable in the for loop.

Another fix is binding the value in the lambda explicitly:

```
myfuns = [lambda arg, clo=clo: str(arg) + str(clo) for clo in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a couple of excellent answers, but to focus on the essence, the difference is due to two design choices Python made:

1. All variable bindings are mutable, and captured as such in closures.
2. `for` comprehensions do not bind a different variable for every iteration, but reassign a new value to the same one.

Neither design choice is necessary, in particular not the latter. For example, in OCaml, the variable of a for-loop is *not* mutable, but a fresh binding for each iteration. Even more interesting, in JavaScript, `for (let x of ...) ...` *will* make `x` mutable (unless you use `const` instead), but it still is separate for every iteration. That fixes the behaviour of JavaScript's older `for (var x in ...)`, which has the same problem as Python and is notorious for leading to subtle bugs with closures.