# Python functools partial definition

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, functools

From [the `functools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), the `partial` function is "roughly equivalent to"

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

However, I don't understand the need for the lines

```
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
```

in the definition. If I create a `partial` function without these three lines it behaves exactly the same as the definition including those lines. The documentation page says that the `partial` object must have the three attributes `func`, `args`, and `keywords`, so I can see why the above function definition inludes these, but I still don't see what tangible goal they accomplish.

Comment: They're are not needed for the `partial` to work, I think, it's just in case if you need some introspection later.

Comment: Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/3001761), *"[the] returned function is decorated with attributes useful for introspection -- the function it's wrapping, and what positional and named arguments it fixes therein"*

Comment: Ok cool! That the lines are there for introspection purpose was my operating assumption but I wasn't completely confident about that.