# How to pass a function with more than one argument to python concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I would like `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` to call a function consisting of 2 or more arguments. In the example below, I have resorted to using a `lambda` function and defining `ref` as an array of equal size to `numberlist` with an identical value.

**1st Question:** Is there a better way of doing this? In the case where the size of numberlist can be million to billion elements in size, hence ref size would have to follow numberlist, this approach unnecessarily takes up precious memory, which I would like to avoid. I did this because I read the `map` function will terminate its mapping until the shortest array end is reach.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf

nmax = 10
numberlist = range(nmax)
ref = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
workers = 3


def _findmatch(listnumber, ref):    
    print('def _findmatch(listnumber, ref):')
    x=''
    listnumber=str(listnumber)
    ref = str(ref)
    print('listnumber = {0} and ref = {1}'.format(listnumber, ref))
    if ref in listnumber:
        x = listnumber
    print('x = {0}'.format(x))
    return x 

a = map(lambda x, y: _findmatch(x, y), numberlist, ref)
for n in a:
    print(n)
    if str(ref[0]) in n:
        print('match')

with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    #for n in executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist):
    for n in executor.map(lambda x, y: _findmatch(x, ref), numberlist, ref):
        print(type(n))
        print(n)
        if str(ref[0]) in n:
            print('match')
```

Running the code above, I found that the `map` function was able to achieve my desired outcome. However, when I transferred the same terms to  concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map(), python3.5 failed with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 241, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7fd2a14db0d0>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

**Question 2**: Why did this error occur and how do I get  concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map() to call a function with more than 1 argument?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer your second question first, you are getting an exception because a `lambda` function like the one you're using is not picklable. Since Python uses the `pickle` protocol to serialize the data passed between the main process and the `ProcessPoolExecutor`'s worker processes, this is a problem. It's not clear why you are using a `lambda` at all. The lambda you had takes two arguments, just like the original function. You could use `_findmatch` directly instead of the `lambda` and it should work.

```
with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    for n in executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist, ref):
        ...
```

As for the first issue about passing the second, constant argument without creating a giant list, you could solve this in several ways. One approach might be to use `itertools.repeat` to create an iterable object that repeats the same value forever when iterated on.

But a better approach would probably be to write an extra function that passes the constant argument for you. (Perhaps this is why you were trying to use a `lambda` function?) It should work if the function you use is accessible at the module's top-level namespace:

```
def _helper(x):
    return _findmatch(x, 5)

with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    for n in executor.map(_helper, numberlist):
        ...
```

Comment: You'r right, I resorted to experimenting `lambda` because I initially had problem passing a function with 2 arguments into the `executor` when `ref` was a constant.  After converting `ref` to a list that is equal size to `numberlist`, I just realised I forgot to remove lambda. What I really wanted was a solution where `ref` is a constant or similar. So the helper function & `itertools.repeat` you mentioned worked.Thanks.

Comment: I like to invite you to answer my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42074501/5722359) where I benchmarked the performance of `Executor.map` with `Executor.submit` and found the former is significantly slower and I like to know why?

Answer (score 11):

(1) No need to make a list. You can use `itertools.repeat` to create an iterator that just repeats the some value.

(2) You need to pass a named function to `map` because it will be passed to the subprocess for execution. `map` uses the pickle protocol to send things, lambdas can't be pickled and therefore they can't be part of the map. But its totally unnecessary. All your lambda did was call a 2 parameter function with 2 parameters. Remove it completely.

The working code is

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import itertools

nmax = 10
numberlist = range(nmax)
workers = 3

def _findmatch(listnumber, ref):    
    print('def _findmatch(listnumber, ref):')
    x=''
    listnumber=str(listnumber)
    ref = str(ref)
    print('listnumber = {0} and ref = {1}'.format(listnumber, ref))
    if ref in listnumber:
        x = listnumber
    print('x = {0}'.format(x))
    return x 

with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    #for n in executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist):
    for n in executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist, itertools.repeat(5)):
        print(type(n))
        print(n)
        #if str(ref[0]) in n:
        #    print('match')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. :)

Comment: I like to invite you to answer my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42074501/5722359) where I benchmarked the performance of `Executor.map` with `Executor.submit` and found the former is significantly slower and I like to know why?

Answer (score 9):

Regarding your first question, do I understand it correctly that you want to pass an argument whose value is determined only at the time you call `map` but constant for all instances of the mapped function? If so, I would do the `map` with a function derived from a "template function" with the second argument (`ref` in your example) baked into it using `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
refval = 5

def _findmatch(ref, listnumber):  # arguments swapped
    ...

with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    for n in executor.map(partial(_findmatch, refval), numberlist):
        ...
```

Re. question 2, first part: I haven't found the exact piece of code that tries to pickle (serialize) the function that should then be executed in parallel, but it sounds natural that that has to happen -- not only the arguments but also the function has to be transferred to the *workers* somehow, and it likely has to be serialized for this transfer. The fact that `partial` functions can be pickled while `lambda`s cannot is mentioned elsewhere, for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279016/6356764.

Re. question 2, second part: if you wanted to call a function with more than one argument in `ProcessPoolExecutor.map`, you would pass it the function as the first argument, followed by an iterable of first arguments for the function, followed by an iterable of its second arguments etc. In your case:

```
for n in executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist, ref):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  :) Your solutions worked. It's my first time learning about partial too.

Comment: I like to invite you to answer my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42074501/5722359) where I benchmarked the performance of `Executor.map` with `Executor.submit` and found the former is significantly slower and I like to know why?

Comment: @mkorvas I used your solution for my question       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492876/unable-to-send-multiple-arguments-to-concurrrent-futures-executor-map