# extracting the longest match

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Consider this simple setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3],
                   'text' : ['stack-overflow',
                             'slack-overflow',
                             'smack-over']})
df
Out[9]: 
   id            text
0   1  stack-overflow
1   2  slack-overflow
2   3      smack-over
```

I have a given regex, and I would like to extract the **longest** match. I know I can use `str.extractall` to get all the matches, but how can I get the longest one efficiently (as a column `df['mylongest']` in the dataframe)?

Of course, in this example the longest matches are overflow, overflow and smack.

```
df.text.str.findall(r'(\w+)')
Out[10]: 
0    [stack, overflow]
1    [slack, overflow]
2        [smack, over]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's map `max` to the result of `str.findall`. I use `functools.partial` to avoid lambdas.

```
from functools import partial

f = partial(max, key=len)
df['text'].str.findall(r'(\w+)').map(f)

0    overflow
1    overflow
2       smack
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks but I really dont understand the `partial` function. Is that a native pandas stuff? can we do that we a good ol lambda func? thanks!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ The alternative would be `df['text'].str.findall(r'(\w+)').map(lambda x: max(x, key=len))`. It's in the standard library, nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I think you will find [Python: Why is functools.partial necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like try something in `pandas`

```
s=df.text.str.extractall(r'(\w+)')[0]
s[s.str.len().eq(s.str.len().max(level=0),level=0)]
Out[51]: 
   match
0  1        overflow
1  1        overflow
2  0           smack
Name: 0, dtype: object
```