# Sort paired array of 3d array (replace for loop)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, vectorization

I have the following 3d array:

```py
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[[10,  2],
               [ 5,  3],
               [ 4,  4]],
              [[ 7,  6],
               [ 4,  2],
               [ 5,  8]]])
```

I want to sort them according to 3rd dim & 1st value.

Currently I am using following code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

np.array([sorted(x,key=itemgetter(0)) for x in z])
array([[[ 4,  4],
        [ 5,  3],
        [10,  2]],

       [[ 4,  2],
        [ 5,  8],
        [ 7,  6]]])
```

I would like to make the code more efficient/faster by removing the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a numpy one liner you can use [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[10,  2],
               [ 5,  3],
               [ 4,  4]],
              [[ 7,  6],
               [ 4,  2],
               [ 5,  8]]])

a[np.arange(0,2)[:,None], a[:,:,0].argsort()]
array([[[ 4,  4],
        [ 5,  3],
        [10,  2]],
       [[ 4,  2],
        [ 5,  8],
        [ 7,  6]]])
```

Which for such small size array takes about the same time, yet scaling up the size will result in quite an improvement, for instance:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

a = np.random.randint(0,10, (2,100_000,2))

%timeit a[np.arange(0,2)[:,None], a[:,:,0].argsort()]
26.9 ms ± 351 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [sorted(x,key=itemgetter(0)) for x in a]
327 ms ± 6.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to achieve the same result without a `for`-loop. And with the sort function being either user-defined, or a lambda, or a partial of `sorted`:

1. By first creating a sort function:

   ```
   >>> def mysort(it):
   ...   return sorted(it, key=itemgetter(0))
   ...
   >>> list(map(mysort, z))
   [[[4, 4], [5, 3], [10, 2]], [[4, 2], [5, 8], [7, 6]]]
   ```
2. Same as above, but with a lambda instead:

   ```
   >>> list(map(lambda it: sorted(it, key=itemgetter(0)), z))
   [[[4, 4], [5, 3], [10, 2]], [[4, 2], [5, 8], [7, 6]]]
   ```
3. With a `partial`:

   ```
   >>> from functools import partial
   >>> psort = partial(sorted, key=itemgetter(0))
   >>> list(map(psort, z))
   [[[4, 4], [5, 3], [10, 2]], [[4, 2], [5, 8], [7, 6]]]
   ```

   Or the partial defined in-place:

   ```
   >>> list(map(partial(sorted, key=itemgetter(0)), z))
   [[[4, 4], [5, 3], [10, 2]], [[4, 2], [5, 8], [7, 6]]]
   ```
4. Your question has a list of lists of lists, rather than a 3d numpy array. For numpy-oriented solutions, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/1431750).

FYI, (2) and (3b) are [roughly equivalent, but have their differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/1431750).
Among options 1-3, my preference is the lambda in (2).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tested them all and it seems the for loop is still the quickest. Does that sound correct to you?

Comment: Are you checking each against a much much longer version of the original list `z`? For such short lists, I don't think the performance difference would be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply : `np.sort(z,axis=1)` ?

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[[10,  2],
               [ 5,  3],
               [ 4,  4]],
              [[ 7,  6],
               [ 4,  2],
               [ 5,  8]]])

print(np.sort(z,axis=1))

[[[ 4  2]
  [ 5  3]
  [10  4]]

 [[ 4  2]
  [ 5  6]
  [ 7  8]]]
```