# Cannot pass class object to starmap in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, starmap

I am have a file and I want to process it in a parallelized manner using Python's multiprocessing class. My current code is:

```
class rand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rando = "world"

def do_work2(obj, line):
    return line + obj.rando

if __name__ == "__main__":

    num_workers = cpu_count() - 2
    pool = Pool(num_workers)
    ran = rand()
    with open("sample.txt") as f:
        # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
        results = pool.starmap(do_work2, zip(ran,f), 4)

    print(results)
```

I expect to see all the lines in my file with a concatenated "world" in the end. However when I run this code I get:

```
TypeError: 'rand' object is not iterable
```

I get why it is happening, but I am just wondering if there is a way by which I can send class objects to a function and then use class object inside that function, all this while multiprocessing.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You could do something like `pool.starmap(do_work2, zip(itertools.repeat(ran), f), 4)`, although that's starting to look like it should be rethought. Will `obj` being passed to `do_word2` always be the same per a given call to `starmap`? If so, I'd just `functools.partial` `do_work2` with `ran` pre-supplied as the first argument, then just use `pool.map` instead of `starmap`.

Comment: Can you put this in a code ? I dont see what you mean. Sounds like partial will work.

Comment: Give me like half an hour. I'm just getting some cleaning done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael notes, the error is coming about because `zip` expects that each of its arguments are iterable, while your `rand` class is not. While Chems' fix works, it needlessly takes up memory, and doesn't account for how large the file is. I'd prefer this way:

```
from itertools import repeat

pool.starmap(do_work2, zip(repeat(ran), f), 4)
```

[`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) produces an infinite number of `ran` objects (until you quit asking for them). This means that it will produce as many `ran`s as `f` has lines, without taking up memory in a separate list before being given to `zip`, and without needing to calculate how many lines `f` has.

I'd just scrap using `pool.starmap` and use normal `pool.map` though. You can wrap your function in another function, and supply `ran` as the first argument. There's two ways of doing this. The quick-and-dirty `lambda` way:

```
pool.map(lambda line: do_work2(ran, line), f, 4)
```

Or, the arguably more correct way of using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

pool.map(partial(do_work2, obj=ran), f, 4)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary) for why you may want to prefer `partial` to a plain `lambda`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a class object to a multiprocessing function, but `zip` requires iterable arguments be passed to it. Something like this may be a little more intuitive:

```
args = [(ran, f) for i in range(10)]
results = pool.starmap(do_work2, args)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap

Keep in mind that a copy of the object is made and sent to each process

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
ran = rand()
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    # repeat the ran
    ran_lines = [ran for _ in range(len(f))]
    # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
    results = pool.starmap(do_work2, zip(rand_lines, f), 4)
```