# Setting additional arguments during lambda function definition in a loop - same result when function is called

Tags: matplotlib, callback, python-3.8

I want to create figure callbacks in a loop, with different additional input arguments to the callback for each figure. In the below code snippet the function prints "B" regardless of which figure I click in.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onclick(event, key):
    print(key)

for k in ["A", "B"]:
    x = np.arange(1,10)
    y = x**2
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(k)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda tmp: onclick(tmp, k))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
lambda tmp: onclick(tmp, k)
```

with

```
functools.partial(onclick, key=k)
```

Full example:

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event, key):
    print(key)

for k in ["A", "B"]:
    x = np.arange(1,10)
    y = x**2
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(k)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', partial(onclick, key=k))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.
I am probably stuck in Matlab thinking when it comes to callback functions, but does anyone know a resource which explains why this does not work in Python I'd be happy to read

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the callback and everything to do with lambda functions, and at what point the value of `k` gets evaluated ("early versus late binding"). As a starting point, I suggest this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252364/2912349).