# passing functions as argument with named parameters

Tags: python

I followed this to pass functions as arguments:

[Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python)

However, I could not figure out how to pass function with its own arguments as names parameters

```
def retry(func, *args):
  func(*args)

def action(args):
  do something

retry(action, arg1, namedArg=arg2)
```

Here I get an exception:

```
TypeError: retry() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedArg'
```

Normally, I can do:

```
action(arg1, namedArg=arg2)
```

Please help/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*args` and it's sibling `**kwargs` are the names generally used for extra arguments and key word arguments.  You are passing a kew word argument when you pass `namedArg=arg2`.

So, try this instead:

```
def retry(func, *args, **kwargs):
  func(*args, **kwargs)

def action(*args, **kwargs):
  do something

retry(action, arg1, namedArg=arg2)
```

If you instead use

```
def action(args, kwargs):
  do something
```

Then you will end up with `args` as a list of arguments and `kwargs` as a dictionary of key word arguments, so in your case

```
args = [arg1]
kwargs = {'namedArg':arg2}
```

Comment: How do I ensure the order of arguments in the target function? Let m try this? thx for quick repsonse

Comment: The order of the arguments in the list will be same as the order passed.  The key word args are a dictionary, so there is no order.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, [keyword arguments in python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

As the error clearly states that `got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedArg'`. where as you are providing only arguments in *args.

You will find plenty of examples to understand keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is functools.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
from functools import partial

def action(arg):
    do something

def action2(arg=1):
    do something

def action3(arg1, arg2=2):
    do something

partial(action, arg1)

partial(action, arg1, arg2=3)
```

Comment: In general you would be right, but the point of the `retry()` function seems to be to repeat the function call if it didn't succeed. In your case, one could give the result of `partial()` to that function and have it call it just like it is. But that doesn't become clear from what you wrote.