# Easiest way to pass a calculation method to a function

Tags: python, function

I want to pass different calculation methods to a function, for example:

```
def example_func(method='mean'):
    result = np.+method([1,2,3,4])
```

What is the easiest and most fruitful way to do this (besides maybe a dictionary....)

Comment: Why not directly pass the method itself rather than string?

Comment: functions are first-class objects. see e,g, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the function object itself, then call it within your function

```
import numpy as np

def do_func(f, arg):
    return f(arg)

>>> do_func(np.mean, [1,2,3,4])
2.5
```

You can see that the argument in the example above (`f`) is itself a function, so you can call it with whatever you want inside your function.

Answer (score 2):

As written, you can do

```
getattr(np, method)([1,2,3,4])
```

or

```
from operator import methodcaller
f = methodcaller(method, [1,2,3,4])
f(np)
```

or just pass the function directly into the other function.  Functions are first-class objects.