# Function for calculation execution time of other functions

Tags: python, function, time

I want to create a function that calculates the execution time of other functions, but when I do that, I get an error like: 'int' object is not callable. What is the problem here?

```
import time


def square(x):
    return x**2


def timer(func):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    func()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(t2-t1)

timer(square(5))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python

Comment: Why don’t you use the `timeit` module?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, your link is useful, for your other question, just want to try with that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to modify your code to make it work, but you'll have to pass in the arguments of `square()` into `timer()` after passing in the function as the first argument:

```
def timer(func, *args, **kwargs):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(t2-t1)

timer(square, 5)
```

Using `*args*` and `**kwargs` lets us deal with functions with arbitrary parameters.

A more convenient way to do this is to use a decorator. It returns a wrapper function around the original function. You don't have to change much in order to time a particular function. Here's an example:

```
def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_name = func.__name__
        print(f"Starting {func_name}")
        
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        output = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        
        print(f"Total time for {func_name}: {t2 - t1:.3f} s\n")
        return output
    
    return wrapper
```

To use it, simply do:

```
@timer
def square(x):
    return x**2

square(5)
```

Or:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

timed_square = timer(square)
timed_square(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`square(5)` return `25`; so you're trying to run your timer on a number ;)

Try instead:

```
import time

def timer(func):
    def f(args):
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        ret = func(args)
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        print('execution time: {}'.format(t2-t1))
        return ret
    return f
    
    
def square(x):
    return x**2
    
timedSqure = timer(square)

res = timedSqure(5)
print(res)
```

Further, I recommend on learning [decorators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html) in python, because with decorators you can make it even more elegant by declaring:

```
@timer
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

See [repl here](https://rextester.com/GLD70165)

And last, per @Heap Overflow's comment: it doesn't make sense to time something that runs so quickly. If you want to benchmark a function you should use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: In Python, annotations are something different, as shown by the very article you have linked.

Comment: @HeapOverflow true that! I updated the answer to include timeit (if they meant to do  benchmarking)

Answer (score 0):

Your `timer` expects a function to call, but you're giving it the *result* of already calling one (and that result isn't a function).

You can do `timer(lambda: square(5))` instead. Then it's your `timer` function that executes the (anonymous) function and thus the expression `square(5)` as intended.