Python function to retry functions is not working
I am testing a simple functionality to retry some python function whenever a specific exception is raised. However my except block is not catching my exception and I can't understand why.
import random

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def retry(fun, max_tries=10):
    for i in range(max_tries):
        try:
           fun()
           break
        except RuntimeError:
            print("Except is working")
            continue

def generate_number(number_list, target_number):
    chosen_number = random.choice(number_list)
    if chosen_number == target_number:
        print(f"MATCH -- Chosen: {chosen_number}, Target: {target_number:}")
    else:
        print(f"NO MATCH -- Chosen: {chosen_number}, Target: {target_number:}")
        raise RuntimeError("Chosen and target numbers do not match.")

retry(generate_number(list1, 4))

Given this code, I would expect that on a number match the function would exit and I should only see the output showing the match. On a mismatch the exception would raise and the next iteration of the for loop would continue. However, on a mismatch the exception is causing the script to exit and not moving to the next iteration as below:
NO MATCH -- Chosen: 6, Target: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    retry(generate_number(list1, 4))
  File "test.py", line 20, in generate_number
    raise RuntimeError("Chosen and target numbers do not match.")
RuntimeError: Chosen and target numbers do not match.

As you can see, my except is not catching this exception for some reason.
Additionally, and this is what is really throwing me for a loop, on a match a TypeError is thrown even though the break should end the for loop immediately.
MATCH -- Chosen: 4, Target: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    retry(generate_number(list1, 4))
  File "test.py", line 8, in retry
    fun()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable


Does this answer your question? How can I bind arguments to a function in Python?

Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python

Yes it does, and it answer some follow-up questions I had as well. Thank you @UpAndAdam

You need to either use partial evaluated functions or pass the function and arguments seperately.
As you have written it you are not passing a function into retry, you are passing the result of the generate_number function call to it.
An example would be:
retry(generate_number, list1, 4)
and to alter the signature of your retry function to take a variable number of args and make the retries argument a name-only argument.
Then inside retry you will have to invoke fun with the proper arguments that were passed into retry.
So you will need to control positional arguments, a remaining argument-list and a named-argument.

retry(generate_number(list1, 4)) is not doing what you think it is. You aren't giving retry the function generate_number as an argument but instead the output of generate_number(list1, 4).
Change retry(generate_number(list1, 4)) to retry(generate_number) and fun() to fun(list1, 4)
Example output after making above changes:
NO MATCH -- Chosen: 2, Target: 4
Except is working
NO MATCH -- Chosen: 6, Target: 4
Except is working
MATCH -- Chosen: 4, Target: 4


You need to pass a function to retry(), not the result of calling the function. You can use lambda to create an anonymous function that calls another function with specific arguments.
retry(lambda: generate_number(list1, 4))


Amazing, this is the next thing I was looking into. I thought to pass in my arguments as below to workaround this but your lambda solution is much more elegant. Thank you!
def retry(*args, **kwargs):
for i in range(kwargs["max_tries"]):
try:
kwargs"fun"
break
except RuntimeError:
continue
retry(list1, 4, max_tries=10, fun=generate_number)
