# Python: pass function as parameter, with options to be set

Tags: python, function, parameters

In Python, I need to call many very similar functions on the **same input arguments** `sampleA` and `sampleB` . The only thing is that some of these functions require an **option** to be set, and some don't.
For example:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(sampleA, sampleB)
[...some actions...]
scipy.stats.mstats.ks_twosamp(sampleA, sampleB, alternative='greater')
[...same actions as above...]
scipy.stats.mstats.mannwhitneyu(sampleA, sampleB, use_continuity=True)
[...same actions as above...]
```

Therefore I would like to pass the names of such functions as input argument of a more generic function `computeStats`, as well as `sampleA` and `sampleB`, but I don't know how to handle options that I sometimes have to use.

```
def computeStats(functionName, sampleA, sampleB, options???):
   functionName(sampleA, sampleB)  #and options set when necessary
   ...some actions...
   return testStatistic
```

How do I specify an option that sometimes has to be set, sometimes not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415812/why-use-kwargs-in-python-what-are-some-real-world-advantages-over-using-named):

```
def computeStats(func, sampleA, sampleB, **kwargs):
   func(sampleA, sampleB, **kwargs)
   ...some actions...
   return testStatistic
```

Then you'll be able to use `computeStats()` like so:

```
computeStats(scipy.stats.mstats.ks_twosamp, sampleA, sampleB, alternative='greater')
```

That said, I am not entirely convinced you need this at all. How about simply

```
def postprocessStats(testStatistic):
   ...some actions...
   return testStatistic

postprocessStats(scipy.stats.mstats.ks_twosamp(sampleA, sampleB, alternative='greater'))
```

?

I think this is easier to read and at the same time is more general.

Comment: Ha! The last solution is cool! As for `**kwargs`, when I don't specify it I guess it's just `None` and I can pass it as an argument with no side-effects, right?

Comment: @RickyRobinson: It's OK to specify no arguments when using `**kwargs`. You'll just get an empty dictionary, and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Note that in `**kwargs` (and `*args`), the names are just conventions. The important bit are [the * and the **](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)