# Pass functions to be executed as parameter in Python

Tags: python

I have function that are implemented inside a class as shown below

`Methods.py`

```
class Perform_stats:

    def get_mean(self,data):
        m = np.mean(data)
        return m 

    def get_rms(self,data):
        r = np.sqrt(np.mean(data**2))
        return r
       ....
```

`Testmethods.py`

```
import Methods as mds

ps = mds.Perform_stats()

df_mean = ps.get_mean(df)

df_rms  = ps.get_rms(df)
```

So in `Testmethods.py` I need to pass the same data `df` to the different function of `Perform_stats` class, is it possible to pass the name of the functions that are to  be implemented as a `list` so that I can call all the functions and get the result as `dict`?

Something like as shown below

```
import Methods as mds

ps = mds.Perform_stats(df,methods=['mean','rms','All']) #All is the default arugument which return a dictionary
```

I found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654390/python-pass-function-as-parameter-with-options-to-be-set) which does the same, but I failed to implement my requirement.

Comment: What is the result you are willing to have and what are you getting at the current state?

Comment: @dstrants Currently I am getting different data frames like df_rms, df_mean. What I need is a dictionary `ps` which stores values returned by the respective functions called in the list which is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Is the `Perform_stats` class just an example? (It should probably be named `PerformStats`, by the way) I think I sort of understand what you're asking, and it seems somewhat unusual, can you provide some more context for this?

Comment: @AMC Yes `Perform_stats` is just an example,  I need to have one API exposed where I give the `list` of functions to be executed as a parameter to in the API. If I give `All` it executes all the functions,  else it I mention only a few list of functions like `['mean', 'rms',....]` only those functions will be executed. This should return the results of the executed function combined as a `dictionary`