# What does **D mean in string.format(**D)?

Tags: python, string.format

I am reading Programming Python and can't figure out what the **D mean in the following codes:

```
>>> D = {'say': 5, 'get': 'shrubbery'}
>>> '%(say)s => %(get)s' % D
'5 => shrubbery'
>>> '{say} => {get}'.format(**D)
'5 => shrubbery'
```

I googled **kwargs in python and most of the results are talking about to let functions take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments.

The string.format(**D) here doesn't look like something to let function take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments because I see the dictionary type variable D is just one argument. But what does it mean here?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs?

Comment: Yes, I did look at that question but I could not make the connections there. The **kwargs there only appears in function def, not when you call the functions or the methods.

Comment: I overlooked the answer to question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1415812/2719588 given by Alex Martelli. He made a very good point of _"As for using **kw in a call, "..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, I'm sure someone will come up with a dissertation later on.

`**D` here means that dictionary `D` will be used to fill in the "named holes" in the string format.  As you can see, `{say}` got replaced by `5` and `{get}` got replaced by `shrubbery`.

Actually, it is the same mechanism as the one used for passing an arbitrary number of parameters to a function; `format` expects as many parameters as the "holes" in the string.  If you want to wrap them up in a dictionary, that's how you do it.

For more information, check [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) and [unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), in Python's documentation, as Prashant suggested.

Comment: The 3 answers combined gave me a clear understanding of what it is. Thanks for your just detailed enough explanation and easy to understand answer!

Answer (score 5):

[Argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**`**D` is used for unpacking arguments. It expands the dictionary into a sequence of keyword assignments**, so...

```
'{say} => {get}'.format(**D)
```

becomes...

```
'{say} => {get}'.format(say = 5, get = shrubbery)
```

The `**kwargs` trick works because **keyword arguments are dictionaries**.