# What is `*args` in a Django BaseCommand handle function for?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

The signature of [`BaseCommand.handle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.handle) is `handle(*args, **kwargs)`.  The documentation [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) only uses the `kwargs` argument.

Are there cases/ways to define command arguments/options such that they will appear as positional arguments to the `handle` function?

Comment: For positional and named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer: "What is `*args` in a Django BaseCommand handle function for?"...**

The `*args` is a way to define the arguments of the `handle(...)` method.

As far as I can tell, in the `BaseCommand.handle(...)`, `args` is not connected to command line argument parsing in any way.

As an aside, using `*` and `**` is common practice in Python when you don't know how many arguments will be passed to the method. The names (e.g. `args`, `kwargs`, `options` are determined by the author of the code, and can be anything.

If you want to learn more about `*` and `**` in Python, some places to start:

- [Use of *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)
- [Why use **kwargs in python? What are some real world advantages over using named arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415812/why-use-kwargs-in-python-what-are-some-real-world-advantages-over-using-named)
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

**To answer: "Are there cases/ways to define command arguments/options such that they will appear as positional arguments to the handle function?"...**

As far as I can tell, no. Assuming you use the `add_arguments(...)` method, arguments from the command line will always get placed in the `options` dict.

**To answer a question that wasn't asked, but maybe will be useful to readers: How can you get a required positional argument in the `handle(...)` method?**

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('required_arg')
        parser.add_argument('-o', '--optional_arg')
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(f"req: '{options['required_arg']}'; opt: '{options['optional_arg']}'")
```

```
python manage.py foo
manage.py foo: error: the following arguments are required: required_arg

python manage.py foo hello
req: 'hello'; opt: 'None'

python manage.py foo hello -o world
req: 'hello'; opt: 'world'
```