# How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, arguments

Suppose I have the following `Button` made with Tkinter in Python:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
win = Tk.Toplevel()
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1)
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=action)
```

The method `action` is called when I press the button, but what if I wanted to pass some arguments to the method `action`?

I have tried with the following code:

```
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=action(someNumber))
```

This just invokes the method immediately, and pressing the button does nothing.

---

<sub>See [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders) for standard techniques (not Tkinter-specific) for solving the problem. Working with callbacks in Tkinter (or other GUI frameworks) has some special considerations because the return value from the callback is useless.</sub>

<sub>If you try to create multiple Buttons in a loop, passing each one different arguments based on the loop counter, you may run into problems due to what is called *late binding*. Please see [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/) for details.</sub>

Comment: frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1) #
 Q. what is the value of frame now ?

Answer (score 405, accepted):

This can be done using a `lambda`, like so:

```
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command= lambda: action(someNumber))
```

This is a simple way to bind the argument without an explicit wrapper method or modifying the original `action`.

Comment: You're still writing wrapper methods, you're just doing it inline.

Comment: Sure but I hoped it was obvious from context how that was meant. Also the advantages still stand: Shorter and you can more easily use it on methods you don't have direct control over, or still want to be able to simply call directly. I find the inner method variant only useful for more complex scenarios (eg for decorators; although there a class is imo clearer too)

Comment: @Voo What is the non-wrapper solution to which **agf** seems to allude to, please ?

Comment: there is no non-wrapper solution.

Comment: This doesn't work if _someNumber_ is in fact a variable that changes values inside a loop that creates many buttons. Then each button will call action() with the last value that has been assigned to _someNumber_ and not the value it had when the button was created. The solution using `partial` works in this case.

Comment: @Scrontch Well yeah obviously that's how variable scoping works in python and pretty much every other language (so it works and if you think about it, it's the only logical way to do things). Several solutions, partial certainly works although old school python people will probably stick to the default parameter assignment for the lambda.

Comment: This worked great for me. However, can you also explain why the OPs statement of `"This just invokes the method immediately, and pressing the button does nothing"` happens?

Comment: OT: Went out of my way to upvote this, thank you.
@Tommy, Just taking a guess, but I think it is because Python handles functions in two stages. callables and actual calls(still new so I don't know the terms). By passing args to a callable, you take the arg from being a reference to a type object to being a call to that object with the specified parameters.

Comment: @Scrontch I wonder how many novice Tkinter users never felt in the trap you mentioned! At any rate one can _capture_ the current value using the idiom `callback=lambda x=x: f(x)` as in `fs = [lambda x=x: x*2 for x in range(5)] ; print [f() for f in fs]`

Comment: @Voo what do you mean above with "although old school python people will probably stick to the default parameter assignment for the lambda"? I did not get lambda to work and thus now use partial.

Comment: My personal case is that `command=something()` does action even if no click is made on button. So strange behavior. Using lambda function constructor is so much better, also allows you to extend the function and does what i expect, run on click :P

Comment: @erm3nda Leave the parens off - you don't want to call that function.

Comment: @Voo: Ask Python devs to remove it from the Python functions and you will know why is in there. Lambda is nothing new, double iteration over a function, literally function constructor. Use it with care ;)

Comment: @erm3nda I have no idea what you're trying to tell me. Your parameter should be `command=something` without the parens otherwise you assign the result of your function to the parameter which you almost certainly don't want.

Comment: I got the same problem than the asker. Even if in theory it should work, doesn't. Every function defined into a button does fire at load, and not when you press button. Did u try in your machine that piece of code?

Comment: [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture/23557126) on the issue pointed by @Scrontch

Comment: This trick actually works, but sadly not with .bind() ; @erm3nda It shouldn't work in "theory". That's how Python is *supposed* to work. You put a function name with '()' - it gets called immediately !

Comment: @elig Not if you put a lambda: in front of it (that's how you designate an anonymous function that takes no arguments and returns the result of the function call), which is why the shown code works just fine.

Answer (score 155):

This can also be done by using `partial` from the standard library [functools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html), like this:

```
from functools import partial
#(...)
action_with_arg = partial(action, arg)
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=action_with_arg)
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=partial(action, arg))`

Comment: Sorry for necro'ing, but how would you do this in the case of two or more arguments?

Comment: `action_with_args = partial(action, arg1, arg2... argN)`

Comment: I'd take this approach because lambda didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this work if `arg` is a string whose value changes during a loop? I want to create many buttons, each of them has to call the same function but with a different value of the argument when pressed. Is this possible?

Comment: @RaymondReddington if you were trying to create multiple widgets in a loop, please see [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/).

Comment: @MicheleIafrancesco yes, it works well with `partial`. To use `lambda` requires a special trick, as seen in [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/).

Comment: Thank you so so much. I just recently started learning Python and was getting so frustrated with its "passing by object reference" system. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

## Example GUI:

Let's say I have the GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Press")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

## What Happens When a Button Is Pressed

See that when `btn` is pressed it calls *its own* function which is very similar to `button_press_handle` in the following example:

```
def button_press_handle(callback=None):
    if callback:
        callback() # Where exactly the method assigned to btn['command'] is being callled
```

with:

```
button_press_handle(btn['command'])
```

You can simply think that `command` option should be set as, the reference to the method we want to be called, similar to `callback` in `button_press_handle`.

---

## Calling a Method([Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)) When the Button is Pressed

***Without* arguments**

So if I wanted to `print` something when the button is pressed I would need to set:

```
btn['command'] = print # default to print is new line
```

Pay close attention to the *lack* of `()` with the `print` method which is omitted in the meaning that: *"This is the method's name which I want you to call when pressed **but** don't call it just this very instant."* However, I didn't pass any arguments for the `print` so it printed whatever it prints when called without arguments.

***With* Argument(s)**

Now If I wanted to also pass arguments to *the method I want to be called* when the button is pressed I could make use of the anonymous functions, which can be created with [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) statement, in this case for `print` built-in method, like the following:

```
btn['command'] = lambda arg1="Hello", arg2=" ", arg3="World!" : print(arg1 + arg2 + arg3)
```

---

## Calling *Multiple* Methods when the Button Is Pressed

***Without* Arguments**

You can also achieve that using `lambda` statement but it is considered bad practice and thus I won't include it here. The good practice is to define a separate method, `multiple_methods`, that calls the methods wanted and then set it as the callback to the button press:

```
def multiple_methods():
    print("Vicariously") # the first inner callback
    print("I") # another inner callback
```

***With* Argument(s)**

In order to pass argument(s) to method that calls other methods, again make use of `lambda` statement, but first:

```
def multiple_methods(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args[0]) # the first inner callback
    print(kwargs['opt1']) # another inner callback
```

and then set:

```
btn['command'] = lambda arg="live", kw="as the" : a_new_method(arg, opt1=kw)
```

---

## Returning Object(s) From the Callback

Also further note that `callback` can't really `return` because it's only called inside `button_press_handle` with `callback()` as opposed to `return callback()`. It does `return` but *not* anywhere outside that function. Thus you should rather *modify* object(s) that are accessible in the current scope.

---

## Complete Example with [global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) Object Modification(s)

Below example will call a method that changes `btn`'s text each time the button is pressed:

```
import tkinter as tk

i = 0
def text_mod():
    global i, btn           # btn can be omitted but not sure if should be
    txt = ("Vicariously", "I", "live", "as", "the", "whole", "world", "dies")
    btn['text'] = txt[i]    # the global object that is modified
    i = (i + 1) % len(txt)  # another global object that gets modified

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="My Button")
btn['command'] = text_mod

btn.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[Mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980499/7032856)

Comment: I think you did not answer the OPs question of multiple buttons in a loop, in which case your 'arg' and 'kw' parameters would all have the value of the last iteration of the loop.  you could rewrite your answer to use 'partial', which solves this issue.

Comment: @greggT As far as I can tell, OP didn't ask about multiple buttons in a loop. However, please see  [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/).

Answer (score 13):

Python's ability to provide default values for function arguments gives us a way out.

```
def fce(x=myX, y=myY):
    myFunction(x,y)
button = Tk.Button(mainWin, text='press', command=fce)
```

See: https://tkdocs.com/shipman/extra-args.html

For more buttons you can create a function which returns a function:

```
def fce(myX, myY):
    def wrapper(x=myX, y=myY):
        pass
        pass
        pass
        return x+y
    return wrapper

button1 = Tk.Button(mainWin, text='press 1', command=fce(1,2))
button2 = Tk.Button(mainWin, text='press 2', command=fce(3,4))
button3 = Tk.Button(mainWin, text='press 3', command=fce(9,8))
```

Answer (score 11):

Just to make the answer of Nae a little bit more elaborate, here is a full blown example which includes the possibility to pass a variable to the callback which contains different values for each button:

```
import tkinter as tk
    
def callback(text):
    print(text)

top = tk.Tk()
Texts=["text1", "text2", "text3"]
Buttons=[]

for i, z in enumerate(Texts):
    Buttons.append(tk.Button(top, text=z, command= lambda ztemp=z : callback(ztemp)))
    Buttons[i].pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

top.mainloop()
```

By defining a temporary variable ztemp, the value of that variable gets fixed at the moment when the button is defined.

Comment: This is a separate/additional concern; the canonical question for this problem is [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/).

Answer (score 6):

Building on Matt Thompsons answer : a class can be made callable so it can be used instead of a function:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Callback:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __call__(self):
        self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def default_callback(t):
    print("Button '{}' pressed.".format(t))

root = tk.Tk()

buttons = ["A", "B", "C"]

for i, b in enumerate(buttons):
    tk.Button(root, text=b, command=Callback(default_callback, b)).grid(row=i, column=0)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use lambda

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def go(text):
    print(text)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: go("hello"))
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

output:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to configure `button` with `lambda` like the following syntax:

```
button['command'] = lambda arg1 = local_var1, arg2 = local_var2 : function(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are all well and good, but you can also try this (which works in a for loop btw):

```
root = Tk()

dct = {"1": [*args], "2": [*args]}
def keypress(event):
    *args = dct[event.char]
    for arg in args:
        pass
for i in range(10):
    root.bind(str(i), keypress)
```

This works because when the binding is set, a key press passes the event as an argument. You can then call attributes off the event like `event.char` to get "1" or "UP" ect. If you need an argument or multiple arguments other than the event attributes. just create a dictionary to store them.

Comment: This is worth highlighting as a *Tkinter-specific* approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it invokes the method immediately and pressing the button does nothing is that `action(somenumber)` is evaluated and its return value is attributed as the command for the button. So if `action` prints something to tell you it has run and returns `None`, you just run `action` to evaluate its return value and given `None` as the command for the button.

To have buttons to call functions with different arguments you can use global variables, although I can't recommend it:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

frame = Tk.Frame(width=5, height=2, bd=1, relief=Tk.SUNKEN)
frame.grid(row=2,column=2)
frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
def action():
    global output
    global variable
    output.insert(Tk.END,variable.get())
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=action)
button.pack()
variable = Tk.Entry(master=frame)
variable.pack()
output = Tk.Text(master=frame)
output.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tk.mainloop()
```

What I would do is make a `class` whose objects would contain every variable required and methods to change those as needed:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(width=5, height=2, bd=1, relief=Tk.SUNKEN)
        self.frame.grid(row=2,column=2)
        self.frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.button = Tk.Button(master=self.frame, text='press', command=self.action)
        self.button.pack()

        self.variable = Tk.Entry(master=self.frame)
        self.variable.pack()

        self.output = Tk.Text(master=self.frame)
        self.output.pack()

    def action(self):
        self.output.insert(Tk.END,self.variable.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    Tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is by defining a class and using instance attributes to remember arguments for the callback. To implement the callback, we can simply use a method of the class which looks up the attribute values from `self` - it doesn't need to have separate parameters at all.

Create the class like so:

```
class Function_Wrapper():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
    def func(self):
        return self.x + self.y + self.z # execute function
```

Then make buttons like:

```
instance1 = Function_Wrapper(x, y, z)
button1  = Button(master, text = "press", command = instance1.func)
```

This approach also allows changing the argument bindings later by simply modifying the class instance:

```
instance1.x = 3
# when `button1` is clicked later and `instance1.func` is called,
# `self.x` will use the new value.
```

Answer (score 2):

I am extremely late, but here is a very simple way of accomplishing it.

```
import tkinter as tk
def function1(param1, param2):
    print(str(param1) + str(param2))

var1 = "Hello "
var2 = "World!"
def function2():
    function1(var1, var2)

root = tk.Tk()

myButton = tk.Button(root, text="Button", command=function2)
root.mainloop()
```

You simply wrap the function you want to use in another function and call the second function on the button press.

Comment: As your code has put `var1` and `var2` in main module, you can skip `function1` at all and put `print` statement in `function2`. Do you refer to other situations which I don't get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda to pass the entry data to the command function if you have more actions to carry out, like this (I've tried to make it generic, so just adapt):

```
event1 = Entry(master)
button1 = Button(master, text="OK", command=lambda: test_event(event1.get()))

def test_event(event_text):
    if not event_text:
        print("Nothing entered")
    else:
        print(str(event_text))
        #  do stuff
```

This will pass the information in the event to the button function. There may be more Pythonesque ways of writing this, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First: if the code to create a button is put in a loop, the `Button` instance will be re-created each time through the loop, which may or may not be desirable.

The reason it always gets the last index is that the callback runs when the button is clicked, not when the program starts. Try storing the value of the variable when the button is created, then have the `lambda` use the stored value.

For example:

```
for entry in stuff_that_is_happening:
    value_store[entry] = stuff_that_is_happening
```

Then, later:

```
Button(..., command= lambda: value_store[1])
```