# How can I pass arguments to Tkinter button's callback command?

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, arguments

I got 2 buttons, respectively named 'ButtonA', 'ButtonB'.
I want the program to print 'hello, ButtonA' and 'hello, ButtonB' if any button is clicked.
My code is as follows:

```
def sayHi(name):
    print 'hello,', name

root = Tk()
btna = Button(root, text = 'ButtonA', command = lambda: text)
btna.pack()
```

When I click ButtonA, error occurs, `text not defined`.

I understand this error, but how can I pass ButtonA's text to lambda?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing argument in python Tkinter button command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/passing-argument-in-python-tkinter-button-command). The other happened 5 hours before by another user. Amazing coincidence!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
...
btnaText='ButtonA'
btna = Button(root, text = btnaText, command = lambda: sayHi(btnaText))
btna.pack()
```

For more information take a look at [Tkinter Callbacks](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm)

Comment: I needed to call my function using `lambda: self.MyFunction(MyParam)` not sure if its worth an edit?

Answer (score 3):

text is not a function in your case. Just have it as:

```
value = 'ButtonA'
btna = Button(root, text = value, command = lambda: sayHi(value))
```

And you will get that working.

Comment: This answer does not show how to print "hello, <name of button>" like the question asks.

Comment: Okay, I did not read the question completely. You just have define the text value before and send it to the lamdba callback.