# Tkinter: Trying to use image and text together, image stays after change

Tags: python, tkinter

guys. I'm writing some code for a school project, and I'm getting a basic application planned out. I'm trying to keep a picture in the def but the image remains after you switch. How can I get it to go away when you change functions? My code:

```
def acceleration():
    var.set("Acceleration \n \n \n \n \n \n Acceleration is defined as: \n 'the increase in the rate or speed of something. \n How could this be used in code?' \n \n \n")
    photo = PhotoImage(file="accel.gif")
    img = Label(root, image=photo)
    img.photo = photo
    img.pack();
```

Thanks Guys!
~Brayden

P.S. I'll gladly give you the entire script if necessary, though I think it won't.

Comment: I would create the label in your main and pass its variable through to the function, then each function, when called, will change the value of the label. This would be a 'pass by reference' in proper computational terms.

Comment: Did you mean to put the var.set("Blah Blah") as a variable, then remove the var.set in the function, and replace it with the variable I gave it? IE: v = var.set("Blah Blah") 

In the function:
    def acceleration():
        photo = PhotoImage(file="accel.gif")
        img = Label(root, image=photo)
        img.photo = photo
        img.pack();

Comment: No, I mean, in your main, do img = Label(root, image=None) and for each function you'll have it as a paramater. i.e. def acceleration(img): this allows all your functions access to the same label. In your code, the label exists in tkinter, but the variable referencing it is destroyed when the function ends.

Comment: I've done that, but I get this error:



Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: acceleration() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: when you call acceleration are you passing the variable through, or is this function being called by a button or some other tk object. If that's the case, I believe you have to use a special setup to pass parameters to the function.

Comment: Yes, I am using a button.. I didn't guess that'd be important. I can put the script on github for you to look at if you'd like?

Comment: this should answer the issue with parameter passing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922621/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-tkinter-buttons-callback-command

Comment: Thanks mate! You were a big help!