# Create a random number of function

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter allows you to assign a function to a button like this:

```
but = Button(master,text="Press Here",command=press_B1).pack()
```

where press_B1 is a defined function.

I have to take an array with n elements and create a button for each one element and if you press for example the first button it print the first element of array.
It simple if I have a defined number of elements but with undefined elements I don't know how to do that.

If I have not explained well what I want to do:

```
arr = ["a","b","c"] #random number of elements
for i in range(len(array)):
    but = Button(master,text="Press Here",command=?).pack()
```

At the end I should have 3 buttons and if I press the first one, python should print "a"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/passing-argument-in-python-tkinter-button-command may be helpful.

Comment: But I don't know what to pass to the function because it depends from the button that I pressed

Comment: @Ermans: you could try passing in `arr[i]` as a first step.

Comment: Doesn't work,It print the value of 'i' after the for loop that is the index of the last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example, you might be able to use function definitions within the loop if you need `print` statements (Python 2.x);

```
arr = ["a","b","c"] #random number of elements
for i in range(len(arr)):
    def f(val=arr[i]):
        print val
    but = Button(None,text="Press Here",command=f).pack()
```

or else you could use a `lambda` instead:

```
import sys
arr = ["a","b","c"] #random number of elements
for i in range(len(arr)):
    lam = lambda val=arr[i]: sys.stdout.write("%s\n"%val)
    but = Button(None,text="Press Here",command=lam).pack()
```

Comment: Both solutions do not work, they just print the last element of the  array. I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @Ermans - you're right I forgot the need to use a default value, updated should work now