# Passing Argument to function python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

class Program:    
    def __init__(self):
        b = Button(text="click me", command=self.callback("1"))
        b.pack()

    def callback(self,s):
        print "clicked!"

program = Program()

mainloop()
```

why execut function befor click button ?? */

Comment: That's not valid Python. Check the comment syntax.

Comment: I EDIT CODE 
CAN NOW ANSWER ME ?

Comment: Please don't yell by using ALL CAPS WORDS.

Comment: why execut function befor click button ?

Comment: What function do you think is executed? Why do you think it should *not* be executed? Do you understand who Tkinter works?

Comment: I want to pass a variable
Based on the value of calls function when the button is pressed

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing argument in python Tkinter button command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/passing-argument-in-python-tkinter-button-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a function reference to `command` argument . Otherwise you execute the function in place.

```
b = Button(text="click me", command=self.callback)
# Or if you want to pass parameters
b = Button(text="click me", command=lambda: self.callback("1"))
```