# changing buttons within tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
win=Tk()
level1=matrixmaker(4)

def display(x,y): 
if z["text"] == " ":
    # switch to Goodbye
    z["text"] = level1[x][y]
else:
    # reset to Hi
    z["text"] = " "


for x in range(0,4):
    for y in range(0,4):
        z=Button(win,text=" ", command=display(x,y))
        z.grid(row=x,column=y)
```

I have this code but I don't know how to get the display function to work. How can I call the button and change the text without it having a hardcoded variable name?

Comment: In Tkinter, the `command` argument is a _reference_ to a function, not the function itself. You have to make the argument into `command=display` with no arguments. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter

Comment: Also, you're calling a three argument function with only two arguments (that can't be added anyway).

Comment: use `command=lambda a=x,b=y:display(a,b)`

Comment: i added the lambda but now whenever i click anything on the grid it only changes the bottom right button

Comment: because you change `z` - but `z` is the last button created in `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign the command to the button with the called function (`display(x, y)`) because this assigned what this function returns (`None`) to the button's command. You need to assign the callable (`display`) instead.

To do this and pass arguments you'll need to use a lambda:

```
z = Button(win, text='')
z['command'] = lambda x=x, y=y, z=z: display(x, y, z)
z.grid(row=x, column=y)
```

Also, you'll want to change your `display()` function to accept another argument `z` so that the correct button gets changed (and correct the indentation):

```
def display(x,y,z): 
    if z["text"] == " ":
        # switch to Goodbye
        z["text"] = level1[x][y]
    else:
        # reset to Hi
        z["text"] = " "
```

Comment: you should add - OP needs to use `def display(x,y,z)` in place of `def display(x,y)`

Comment: @furas Thanks for pointing this out (before the OP edited the question it was defined as `def display(x,y,z)`)