# Problems assigning a value from a randomly populated array to a tkinter button

Tags: python, arrays, button, tkinter

Hello I am trying to create a game where you click on a button and it tells you if it is treasure or a bandit.  It if is treasure then you get points if it is a bandit you loose your coins.
I have created the following code but cannot find a way of finding out if I have managed to set the buttons to the values stored in the array.
How do you use the data in the array and when a button is clicked it tells you what the value is.
Am I doing the array correctly any help would be appreciated I am going round in circles and cannot think straight now.

```
from tkinter import *  
import tkinter.messagebox  
import random

#count=0

root = Tk()  
TreasureMap = Frame(root)  
TreasureMap.grid()  

root.title("TreasureMap")  
text_box = Entry(TreasureMap, justify=RIGHT)

text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 8,)  
text_box.insert(0, "0")  

amount_to_add='B'  
my_array = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)  

Treasure='T'
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)    
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure) 
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  
my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(Treasure)  


print(my_array)  


def changelabel():  `   
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Hellow this button works') `` 
        print('hello this button works') ` ``  
        print(my_array)  ``  ``   
        return  



i = 0  
bttn = []  
for j in range(1,9):`     
     for k in range(8):  ``    
     bttn.append(Button(TreasureMap, text = ' ', value=random.shuffle      
     (my_array),command=changelabel))       
     bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k)           
     i += 1  ``     


 TreasureMap.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're wanting to do.
Borrowing info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter), I put a [callback](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) in the Button command to pass the row and column numbers.
Also, 'B' and 'T' are being appended to each array of `0`'s, instead of getting assigned to locations within the array, which is what I think you want.
I made a few other changes, including fixing the `for` loops to start from `0` (the first row), etc.

```
# previous code

amount_to_add='B'  
my_array = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]  

# ... all code up to here unchanged ...

for _ in range(4):
    my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))][random.randrange(len(my_array))] = amount_to_add   

Treasure='T'
for _ in range(4):
    my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))][random.randrange(len(my_array))] = Treasure  

# print my_array # uncomment to check array values before shuffle
random.shuffle(my_array)
# print my_array # and after shuffle to confirm button is getting the correct values

def changelabel(j,k):
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Button %d,%d' % (j,k), 'Button %d,%d contains a %s' % (j,k, my_array[j][k]))
        print('hello this button works')
        # return # not needed  

i = 0  
bttn = []

for j in range(0,8):   
    for k in range(8):
        bttn.append(Button(TreasureMap, text = ' ', command= lambda row = j, column = k: changelabel(row, column)))
        bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k)           
        i += 1
```

Feel free to comment or ask questions if this doesn't do what you were asking for. Otherwise, hope it helps.

Comment: what does command= lambda row = j, column=k: changelabel(row,column)     do in this code??

Comment: command is the argument passed to the Button just as you had used it. However we also want to include parameters to `changelabel` for it to know which row/column the button was being called from. [The callback can be a function, bound method, or any other callable Python object](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method), here `changelabel` *is that function* and the [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) assigns `j` and `k` at runtime as parameters to pass to `changelabel`