# How to put what a function returns into a label?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So first a little disclaimer:
I'm pretty to new to programming in general and i have alot to learn. so my code will probably seem very sloppy and ridiculous. So i am sorry for that.

I am trying to make a simple gui program that takes text entered by the user and turns it into gibberish from a dictionary i made. So with this you can encrypt and decrypt text. this is the console script i made:

```
 `list = {"a": "l", "b": "k", "c": "j", "d": "h", "e": "g", "f": "d", "g": "f", "h": "d", "i": "s", "j": "a", "k": "q", "l": "w", "m": "e", "n": "r", "o": "t", "p": "y", "q": "u", "r": "z", "s": "x", "t": "c", "u": "m", "v": "n", "w": "p", "x": "b", "y": "i", "z": "o", " ": " "} 
list_2 = {"l": "a", "k": "b", "j": "c", "h": "d", "g": "e", "d": "f", "f": "g", "d": "h", "s": "i", "a": "j", "q": "k", "w": "l", "e": "m", "r": "n", "t": "o", "y": "p", "u": "q", "z": "r", "x": "s", "c": "t", "m": "u", "n": "v", "p": "w", "b": "x", "i": "y", "o": "z", " ": " "}


def encrypt():
    user_input = raw_input("what is the messge?:\n")

    for char in user_input:
        print list[char.lower()],


def decrypt():
    user_input = raw_input("what is the messge?:\n")

    for char in user_input:
        print list_2[char.lower()],


which_one = raw_input("type 1 for encrypt, type 2 for decrypt:\n")


if which_one == "1":
    encrypt()
elif which_one == "2":
    decrypt()
else:
    print "ERROR!"
`
```

so now I'm trying to implement the same idea but with a gui using tkinter. Where I'm stuck is trying to basically print what the result is somewhere.  This is what i have so far:

```
    from Tkinter import *

list = {"a": "l", "b": "k", "c": "j", "d": "h", "e": "g", "f": "d", "g": "f", "h": "d", "i": "s", "j": "a", "k": "q", "l": "w", "m": "e", "n": "r", "o": "t", "p": "y", "q": "u", "r": "z", "s": "x", "t": "c", "u": "m", "v": "n", "w": "p", "x": "b", "y": "i", "z": "o", " ": " "} 
list_2 = {"l": "a", "k": "b", "j": "c", "h": "d", "g": "e", "d": "f", "f": "g", "d": "h", "s": "i", "a": "j", "q": "k", "w": "l", "e": "m", "r": "n", "t": "o", "y": "p", "u": "q", "z": "r", "x": "s", "c": "t", "m": "u", "n": "v", "p": "w", "b": "x", "i": "y", "o": "z", " ": " "}

root = Tk()
encrypt_entry_var = StringVar()
decrypt_entry_var = StringVar()


def encrypt(encrypt_entry_var):
    for char in encrypt_entry_var:
        return list

results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var)
results_label = Label(root, str(results))



encrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=encrypt_entry_var)
encrypt_button = Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt)
decrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=decrypt_entry_var)
decrypt_button = Button(root, text="Decrypt")

encrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
encrypt_button.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_button.pack(fill=X)

root.title("Encryption Chat")
root.geometry("500x90")




mainloop()
```

This is the error i get:

```
Current directory: C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects
C:\Python27\python.exe -u "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py", line 15, in <module>
    results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var)
  File "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py", line 12, in encrypt
    for char in encrypt_entry_var:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Any help would be very appreciated.I hope i gave enough information to help you understand. Thank you all for your time and have a nice day!!!

Update:
so now this is the error im getting:

```
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py", line 21, in <module>
    encrypt_button = Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt(encrypt_entry_var))
  File "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py", line 12, in encrypt
    for char in encrypt_entry_var:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

I do not understand what iteration over non-sequence exactly means. I could not wrap my head around what google had to say about it. I've never had this error in previous projects.

Updated code:

```
from Tkinter import *

list = {"a": "l", "b": "k", "c": "j", "d": "h", "e": "g", "f": "d", "g": "f", "h": "d", "i": "s", "j": "a", "k": "q", "l": "w", "m": "e", "n": "r", "o": "t", "p": "y", "q": "u", "r": "z", "s": "x", "t": "c", "u": "m", "v": "n", "w": "p", "x": "b", "y": "i", "z": "o", " ": " "} 
list_2 = {"l": "a", "k": "b", "j": "c", "h": "d", "g": "e", "d": "f", "f": "g", "d": "h", "s": "i", "a": "j", "q": "k", "w": "l", "e": "m", "r": "n", "t": "o", "y": "p", "u": "q", "z": "r", "x": "s", "c": "t", "m": "u", "n": "v", "p": "w", "b": "x", "i": "y", "o": "z", " ": " "}

root = Tk()
encrypt_entry_var = StringVar()
decrypt_entry_var = StringVar()


def encrypt(encrypt_entry_var):
    for char in encrypt_entry_var:
        return list

results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var.get())
results_label = Label(root, text=str(results))



encrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=encrypt_entry_var)
encrypt_button = Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt(encrypt_entry_var))
decrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=decrypt_entry_var)
decrypt_button = Button(root, text="Decrypt")

encrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
encrypt_button.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_button.pack(fill=X)
results_label.pack

root.title("Encryption Chat")
root.geometry("500x90")




mainloop()
```

Comment: To get the text from the `StringVar()` it'll be `results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var.get())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you are passing to the function is of type `StringVar` which is not `string`, its a wrapper around the python `string` type.

From the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) -

> If you program Tk using the Tcl language, you can ask the system to
>   let you know when a variable is changed. The Tk toolkit can use this
>   feature, called tracing, to update certain widgets when an associated
>   variable is modified.
>
> There’s no way to track changes to Python variables, but Tkinter
>   allows you to create variable wrappers that can be used wherever Tk
>   can use a traced Tcl variable.

What you simply need to do is change this line

```
results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var)
```

to

```
results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var.get())
```

FIXED CODE -

```
from Tkinter import *

# changed variable name
list_1 = {"a": "l", "b": "k", "c": "j", "d": "h", "e": "g", "f": "d", "g": "f", "h": "d", "i": "s", "j": "a", "k": "q", "l": "w", "m": "e", "n": "r", "o": "t", "p": "y", "q": "u", "r": "z", "s": "x", "t": "c", "u": "m", "v": "n", "w": "p", "x": "b", "y": "i", "z": "o", " ": " "} 
list_2 = {"l": "a", "k": "b", "j": "c", "h": "d", "g": "e", "d": "f", "f": "g", "d": "h", "s": "i", "a": "j", "q": "k", "w": "l", "e": "m", "r": "n", "t": "o", "y": "p", "u": "q", "z": "r", "x": "s", "c": "t", "m": "u", "n": "v", "p": "w", "b": "x", "i": "y", "o": "z", " ": " "}

root = Tk()
encrypt_entry_var = StringVar()
decrypt_entry_var = StringVar()


def encrypt(encrypt_entry_var):
    # fixed encrypt function 
    return ''.join([list_1[char.lower()] for char in encrypt_entry_var])

results = encrypt(encrypt_entry_var.get())
results_label = Label(root, text=str(results))



encrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=encrypt_entry_var)
# pass a lambda function calling your encrypt function
encrypt_button = Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=lambda : encrypt(encrypt_entry_var))
decrypt_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=decrypt_entry_var)
decrypt_button = Button(root, text="Decrypt")

encrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
encrypt_button.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_entry.pack(fill=X)
decrypt_button.pack(fill=X)
results_label.pack

root.title("Encryption Chat")
root.geometry("500x90")

mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! now the problem i have is :   File "C:\Users\Cody Pickett\Desktop\Coding\current projects\Encrypyion_chat_wgui.py", line 16, in <module>
    results_label = Label(root, str(results))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2597, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2091, in __init__
    for k in cnf.keys():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================

Comment: i have no idea what that error is talking about o.0

Comment: You are not instantiating the Label object correctly, the correct syntax is `results_label = Label(root, text=str(results))` and I do expect your `encrypt` function returns something contrary to the example stated. BTW username checks out lol

Comment: oh i see its because i have str(results) ?

Comment: @thatsyntaxerrorguy Its again because of a syntax error, you cannot pass a function which takes arguments as `command` in tkinter Button. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter) out.

Comment: @thatsyntaxerrorguy And also, your `encrypt` function is not going to work fine, its returning on its first iteration which it shouldn't.

Comment: @thatsyntaxerrorguy Also avoid naming variables which are python keywords, like you have named `list`.