# My combobox will only run once

Tags: tkinter, combobox

```
            from tkinter import *
            from tkinter.ttk import *

            month  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

            def func1(self,event = None):
                var = self.CB1.get()
                print(var)
                print("Your Birthday is: " + var)


            class app():
                def __init__(self):

                    window = Tk()


                    self.CB1 = Combobox(window,values = month,state = "readonly")
                    self.CB1.current(0)

                    self.CB1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", func1(self,event = None))

                    self.CB1.pack()

                    window.mainloop()


            app()
```

So it will output 1, and say "Your birthday is 1", it will not do it again if I select a different number. I have tried over 10 different pages to understand combo-boxes, and am failing quite hard to understand. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you to all who help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in the line

```
self.CB1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", func1(self,event = None))
```

`func1` is executed directly and the result (`None`) is assigned as the bind "function". Use a lambda expression like this:

```
self.CB1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda x: func1(self, x))
```

Now you're binding an anonymous function to the event without executing it.

Answer (score 1):

The @TidB answer about `lambda` function and why your combobox runs only once is absolutely correct!

But I'm confused by how you built your class and how you passed `self` and `event` outside the class. Is it really what you want or are you trying to do something like this?

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

month = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()

        self.CB1 = ttk.Combobox(window, values=month, state="readonly")
        self.CB1.current(0)
        self.CB1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.func1)
        self.CB1.pack()

        window.mainloop()

    def func1(self, event=None):
        var = self.CB1.get()
        print(var)
        print("Your Birthday is: " + var)

App()
```

Python passes your `self` and `event` for you implicitly, so why're you trying to do a same job?
So I think that a real problem stems from your class's structure. And this is a real cause why your combobox runs only once.

- [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)
- [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)
- [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
- [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)