# check what button in a list has been pressed with bind tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, bind

I have a list of buttons and when I run a function I need to check what button in that list was pressed.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def Function(event):
    print('The pressed button is:')

listOfButtons = []
Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 1")
listOfButtons.append(Button)
Button.pack()
Button.bind("<Button-1>", Function)

Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 2")
Button.pack()
listOfButtons.append(Button)
Button.bind("<Button-1>", Function)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `bind` on buttons, just use their `command` option when you create them.

Comment: Not only you don't need to use `bind` but you're limitating your button to able to run `Function` if and only if it is pressed using mouse left click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all buttons in the list, and check `if button is event.widget`:

```
def Function(event):
    for button in listOfButtons:
        if button is event.widget:
            print(button['text'])
            return
```

As @tobias_k mentioned - it's overcomlicated. You already has a `button` as `event.widget`. So solution is simple as `print(event.widget['text'])`. However, if `Function` can be called not only from the button click or there're several lists with buttons/with whatever  - it's a must to check!

In other side, button can be pressed not only by the Left-mouse click, hence `command` option is better!

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def Function(button):
    print(button['text'])


...
Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 1")
Button.configure(command=lambda button=Button: Function(button))
...


Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 2")
Button.configure(command=lambda button=Button: Function(button))
...

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because `print(event.widget['text'])` would be too easy?

Comment: @tobias_k That's a great solution and an odd way to suggest improvement at the same time.

Comment: @tobias_k, yeah, you're right. I "overthinked" _what button in a list has been pressed_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def Function(event):
    if event == 1:
        print('The pressed button is: 1')
    if event == 2:
        print('The pressed button is: 2')

listOfButtons = []
Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 1", command= lambda: Function(1))
listOfButtons.append(Button)
Button.pack()

Button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 2",command= lambda: Function(2))
Button.pack()
listOfButtons.append(Button)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to do `command= lambda: Function(1)` otherwise, you execute the function on button creation, not when it is clicked.

Comment: You are right ,i corrected it.I was thinking that something is wrong and found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter and saw the command  :D