# Destroy Tkinter button after click

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter list box populated with city names. I want to grab the selected value and pass it to subsequent code after the mainloop. I have the following tkinker code:

```
master = tk.Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(cities_list[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *cities_list)
w.pack()

def ok():
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())
    return  variable.get()
    window.destroy()


button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()


v_list = variable.get().split('-')
```

The button is stuck in a loop and will not close. I want to close the button after a selection. I've tried both "window.destroy()" and "master.destroy()"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `window` at the very least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button doesn't `destroy` because its function 'returns' before doing so. Which is also bad because a `command`'s [callback method can't really `return` anywhere meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996979/7032856). Do the following changes:

```
some_outer_scope_var = None

def ok():
    global some_outer_scope_var
    some_outer_scope_var = variable.get()
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())
    master.destroy()
```

That way you save the value of `variable.get()` on `some_outer_scope_var` first and then `destroy` all GUI.

Comment: It turns out that variable was in the outer scope. I removed "some_outer_scope_var = variable.get()" and it started working.

Comment: @user61629 Shouldn't be the case unless you have multiple instances of `Tk`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
    button.destroy()
if you want to destroy the button only.