# TypeError: login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'

Tags: python, tkinter, authentication, arguments, typeerror

I have the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from customer import Customer
from admin import Admin
from account import Account
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

global username
global password


def login(self, username, password):
    name = username.get()
    passphrase = password.get()
    msg = self.customer_login(name, passphrase)




root.config(height=500, width=500)
frame = Frame(root)
Label(root, text="Login").grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

Label(root, text="Username").grid(row=3, sticky=W, padx=4)
username = Entry(root).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
Label(root, text="Password").grid(row=4, sticky=W, padx=4,)
password = Entry(root, show="*").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

loginButton = Button(root, text="Login", width=40)
loginButton.grid(row=5, columnspan=4, pady=4, padx=4)
loginButton.bind("<Button-1>", login)


root.mainloop()
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: You're trying to pass only one argument to a method that needs no arguments but _does_ require 3 arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass only one argument to a method that in actuality needs no arguments but *does* require 3 arguments.

When a callback, `login`, is attached to a `bind` method, it is sent a positional argument that represents the information about the event, usually named `event` even though not explicitly passed like you did. In which case it is assumed that `self` is representing the event positional argument. Though now `login` lacks two positional arguments, `username` and `password`. Now if you actually needed those variables I'd have provided a different answer but since you don't this is the simplest I can think of.

Replace:

```
def login(self, username, password):
```

with:

```
def login(event):
```

Also, see [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920302/7032856) as you probably would want to use `command`option of a button as opposed to a click event which *won't* call the method if the button is pressed with keyboard, and also `bind` and `command` act similarly in the sense that they both require a callback function. The only difference is that `bind` implicitly passes a 1st positional argument.

Comment: Thanks! Although editing login() did not work, I decided to research command as you suggested and have got it working that way. Many thanks!

Comment: There are some other things that are wrong with the code you've provided. There is no `self.customer_login(name, passphrase)` for one and also `username` and `password` are stored as `None` as they're the return of method `grid`. Call `grid`s on separate lines, remove `msg = ...` line and it should give no more error(s).