# missing required arguments, multiprocessing in class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

so recently i wanted to try using multiprocessing in my work script, so i made this dummy just to see if i can make it work with a class and i am getting errors.

Can anyone tell me how i can solve this issue?

```
from multiprocessing import Process


class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting")

    def login(self, auth_user, auth_pass):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'Username: {auth_user}\nPassword: {auth_pass}')

    def say_hello(self, how_many_times):
        for i in range(how_many_times):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f'Times: {i}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = A()

    auth = {
        'username': 'jnk',
        'password': 'test'
    }

    p1 = Process(target=a.login(), args=(auth['username'], auth['password'],))
    p2 = Process(target=a.say_hello(), args=(5,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Error:

```
Starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    p1 = Process(target=a.login(), args=(auth['username'], auth['password'],))
TypeError: login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'auth_user' and 'auth_pass'
```

Thanks for replies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *calling* the functions - you have to provide them to the Process:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = A() 
    auth = { 'username': 'jnk', 'password': 'test' }

    # provide the functions - DO NOT CALL THEM - do not place () after them:    
    p1 = Process(target=a.login, args=(auth['username'], auth['password'],))
    p2 = Process(target=a.say_hello, args=(5,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Output:

```
Starting
Username: jnk
Password: test
Times: 0
Times: 1
Times: 2
Times: 3
Times: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179778/typeerror-login-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-username-and-pass?rq=1) and you'll find a detailed answer there. Shortly put, replace

`def login(self, auth_user, auth_pass):`

with

`def login (event):`

That error message was gone, but I got another error message stating that `time` is not defined. But I suspect it's defined somewhere else, in a part of the code that is not here.

Comment: Not the reason - the reason is he is _calling_ the functions where he only should provide them to be called _by Process_.

Comment: You are essentially reducing the `def login` class instance function taking 2 params and self to a 0-param login function where the _instance_ normally named `self` is provided by the name `event` itself.

Comment: when called it silently crashes in the other thread and does not print the given parameters... essentially you converted broken code into **silently** broken code.