# Setting up a workflow with `after` using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a pre-defined GUI workflow (i.e., pipeline) using the `after` method of Tkinter, but it does not work and I am confused.

As a minimal example, I have created this simple GUI:

```
from tkinter import *

class example:

    global frame, rect, text

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.initialize()
        self.workflow()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        global frame, rect, text
        # frame
        frame = Canvas(self.root, width=500, height=500, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # rectangle
        rect = frame.create_rectangle(20, 20, 400, 350, fill='blue')
        # text
        text = frame.create_text(250, 250, text='FIRST...', fill='#ffff00', font=("Purisa", 20, "bold"))

    def change_message(self, new_message):
        global frame, text
        frame.itemconfig(text, text=new_message)

    def workflow(self):
        global frame, rect, text
        self.root.after(2000, self.change_message("SECOND..."))
        self.root.after(4000, self.change_message("END"))

myExample = example()
```

The aim is to follow the pipeline that is specified in the `workflow` method, which is the following:

- 1st: The message shows the text "FIRST..." when the application is run
- 2nd: After 2 seconds, the text changes and shows "SECOND..."
- 3rd: After 4 seconds, the text changes again and shows "END"

But, when I run this example, the GUI waits 4 seconds to show up, and displays the final "END" message, without plotting the previous changes...

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `self.root.update()` between each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.root.after(2000, self.change_message("SECOND..."))
self.root.after(4000, self.change_message("END"))
```

with either:

```
self.root.after(2000, lambda : self.change_message("SECOND..."))
self.root.after(4000, lambda : self.change_message("END"))
```

or, like in [Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)['s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368731/setting-up-a-workflow-with-after-using-tkinter/48368773?noredirect=1#comment83728555_48368773), with:

```
self.root.after(2000, self.change_message, "SECOND...")
self.root.after(4000, self.change_message, "END")
```

---

`.after(ms, callback, *args)` requires `callback` to be a reference as opposed to an actual call to the `callback` function. Basically ditch `()` from `callback()` to have `callback`.

When `callback()` is passed instead of `callback`, as in:

```
widget.after(ms, callback(), *args)
```

python acts roughly equivalent to:

```
callback(*args)
time.sleep(ms / 1000)
```

which delays the execution of `mainloop()` line, thus GUI is displayed late.

---

This is has some similarity to [how button commands work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996979/7032856.).

Comment: You don't need to use `lambda` with `after`. You can pass additional arguments without it: `self.root.after(2000, self.change_message, "SECOND")`

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks again, hopefully, 3rd time I will remember that.

Comment: Your solution works, but it adds unnecessary complexity. Tkinter beginners seem to think that `lambda` is a cure-all. IMO it should only be used when it's absolutely necessary because it makes debugging more difficult.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, I find it easier with `lambda` as I can connect the dots easier for callbacks to be used with options such as `bind`, `trace_add`, `command`. Then again I'm a beginner as well.