# Lambda method is not getting called in the python program

Tags: database, tkinter, python-3.5

I am working on a project based on GUI working on python. In the button command on passing the method of the self class there is no effect i.e the method is not getting called. **there is no compile time or runtime error showing up** because of which it is very difficult to identify the problem. The source code is:

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

```
def e_detail(self):
    soh_registeration.insert(u1.get(),p1.get(),s1.get(),m1.get(),em1.get(),ad1.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("DETAIL STORED", "YOUR INFORMATION IS STORED SECURELY")

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="REGISTERATION DETAILS", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(pady=10,padx=10)
    label1 = tk.Label(self, text="USERNAME", font=TEXT)
    label1.grid(row=3,column=0)
    labelp = tk.Label(self, text="PASSWORD", font=TEXT)
    labelp.grid(row=4,column=0)
    cpdl = tk.Label(self, text="CONFIRM PASSWORD", font=TEXT)
    cpdl.grid(row=5,column=0)
    shopl = tk.Label(self, text="SHOP NAME", font=TEXT)
    shopl.grid(row=6,column=0)
    cl= tk.Label(self, text="MOBILE NO.:", font=TEXT)
    cl.grid(row=7,column=0)
    el = tk.Label(self, text="E-MAIL ID", font=TEXT)
    el.grid(row=8,column=0)
    al = tk.Label(self, text="AADHAR DETAIL", font=TEXT)
    al.grid(row=9,column=0)

    global u1,p1,p2,s1,m1,em1,ad1,button2
    u1=tk.StringVar()
    username= tk.Entry(self,textvariable=u1, bd=5)
    username.grid(row=3,column=1)

    p1=tk.StringVar()
    pd= tk.Entry(self,show='*',textvariable=p1, bd=5)
    pd.grid(row=4,column=1)

    p2=tk.StringVar()
    confpd= tk.Entry(self,show='*',textvariable=p2, bd=5)
    confpd.grid(row=5,column=1)

    s1=tk.StringVar()
    sn= tk.Entry(self,textvariable=s1, bd=5)
    sn.grid(row=6,column=1)

    m1=tk.StringVar()
    cn= tk.Entry(self,textvariable=m1, bd=5)
    cn.grid(row=7,column=1)

    em1=tk.StringVar()
    email= tk.Entry(self,textvariable=em1, bd=5)
    email.grid(row=8,column=1)

    ad1=tk.StringVar()
    an= tk.Entry(self,textvariable=ad1, bd=5)
    an.grid(row=9,column=1)




    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="SUBMIT YOUR DETAILS",
                        command=lambda: self.e_detail)
    button2.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
```

*as the source code is too long the two blocks where i am finding the problem are mentioned below separately too*:

```
def e_detail(self):
    soh_registeration.insert(u1.get(),p1.get(),s1.get(),m1.get(),em1.get(),ad1.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("DETAIL STORED", "YOUR INFORMATION IS STORED SECURELY")
```

and:-

```
 button2 = tk.Button(self, text="SUBMIT YOUR DETAILS",
                        command=lambda: self.e_detail)
 button2.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
```

i guess the problem would be very basic. I am still new to python programming someone please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `self.e_detail` is not called.

```
, command=lambda: self.e_detail
```

basically tells the button to call an anonymous method that *mentions* a method named `self.e_detail`. Instead make it *call* the method by replacing it with:

```
, command=lambda: self.e_detail()
```

or since the method is not passed any arguments, simply:

```
, command=self.e_detail
```

Comment: generally on adding () in a button command the commands gets executed at the compile time only instead of getting executed at the run time i.e on button click.

Comment: the last method solved the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AyushMishra _Both_ of the code lines suggested supposed to work.