# How Do I Call a Function/Procedure with a GUI button?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a simple client program that connects to a server and sends some information across. It originally used the input function to send over data, but I'd like it to be in a GUI, so you can press a button to send the data across. But I keep getting a name error, it says `sendinfo` is not defined when I try to call it using a button.

```
# client.py

import socket import sys from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

#clients_input = input("What you want to proceed my dear client?\n")
#soc.send(clients_input.encode("utf8")) # we must encode the string to bytes
#result_bytes = soc.recv(4096) # the number means how the response can be in bytes
#result_string = result_bytes.decode("utf8") # the return will be in bytes, so decode

#print("Result from server is {}".format(result_string))

class GUI:
    # some sort of initialise
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Our Server GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our Server GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Send", command=sendinfo(self))
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack() class DataSend:
    def sendinfo(self):
        test = 666
        soc.send(test.encode("utf8"))
        result_byte = soc.recv(4096)
        result_strings = result_byte.decode("utf8")
        print("Result from server is {}".format(result_strings))

## Run program to
## 1 - Open a GUI root = Tk() my_gui = GUI(root)

root.mainloop() #Runs the GUI on a loop so it always shows?
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\stuar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe
F:/College/CyberLvl5/Feb/Programming/TestClient.py Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"F:/College/CyberLvl5/Feb/Programming/TestClient.py", line 43, in
<module>
    my_gui = GUI(root)   File "F:/College/CyberLvl5/Feb/Programming/TestClient.py", line 27, in
__init__
    self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Send", command=sendinfo(self)) NameError: name 'sendinfo' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `command=self.sendinfo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 2):

With the line

```
self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Send", command=sendinfo(self))
```

you tell Python "call the global function `sendinfo` with parameter `self` and bind the result of that function call to `command`". But a *global* function of that name does not exist, and invoking it and binding the result to `command` does not make sense, either. Instead, you want to bind the *method* `sendinfo` *of* `self` *itself* to the command, just like you did for the close button.

```
self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Send", command=self.sendinfo)
```