# TypeError: calculations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entries'

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, syntax-error

I´m new to python and I have written this code but I´m getting an error I do not know how to resolve, could someone help me, please?

```
from tkinter import *
def calculations(entries):
  shaftdia = float(entries['Shaft Diameter'].get())
  outdia = 2 * shaftdia
  thickfork = 0.75*shaftdia
  thicksingleye = 1.75*shaftdia
  diapin = shaftdia
  diapincollar = 1.5*shaftdia

  print("Outer diameter of eye: %f" % float(outdia))
  print("Thickness of fork: %f" % float(thickfork))
  print("Thickness of single eye: %f" % float(thicksingleye))
  print("Diameter of pin: %f" % float(diapin))
  print("Diameter of knuckle pin and collar: %f" % float(diapincollar))

 master = Tk()
 Label(master, text="Shaft Diameter").grid(row=0)
 Label(master, text="Outer diameter of eye").grid(row=1)
 Label(master, text="Thickness of fork").grid(row=2)
 Label(master, text="Thickness of single eye").grid(row=3)
 Label(master, text="Diameter of Pin").grid(row=4)
 Label(master, text="Diameter of knuckle pin head and collar").grid(row=5)

 e1 = Entry(master)
 e2 = Entry(master)
 e3 = Entry(master)
 e4 = Entry(master)
 e5 = Entry(master)
 e6 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=50)
e2.grid(row=1, column=50)
e3.grid(row=2, column=50)
e4.grid(row=3, column=50)
e5.grid(row=4, column=50)
e6.grid(row=5, column=50)


Button(master, text='ACCEPT', command=calculations).grid(row=10, column=1, 
sticky=W, pady=4)


master.mainloop( )
```

It is giving me this error on clicking on the button and I'm unable to resolve the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"C:\Users\kunal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: calculations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entries'
```

If there is any other error please tell because NOOB IN PYTHON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is the function `command` expects `entries` as an argument, which you have not given on `button` click.

As you have assigned the text box entries to `e1,e2,e3,...,e6` you need not pass `entries` at all to the `command` function.

Instead, modify your code like this and it works:

```
from tkinter import *
def calculations():
  shaftdia = float(e1.get())
  outdia = 2 * shaftdia
  thickfork = 0.75*shaftdia
  thicksingleye = 1.75*shaftdia
  diapin = shaftdia
  diapincollar = 1.5*shaftdia

  print("Outer diameter of eye: %f" % float(outdia))
  e2_var.set(outdia)
  print("Thickness of fork: %f" % float(thickfork))
  e3_var.set(thickfork)
  print("Thickness of single eye: %f" % float(thicksingleye))
  e4_var.set(thicksingleye)
  print("Diameter of pin: %f" % float(diapin))
  e5_var.set(diapin)
  print("Diameter of knuckle pin and collar: %f" % float(diapincollar))
  e6_var.set(diapincollar)
master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Shaft Diameter").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Outer diameter of eye").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Thickness of fork").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="Thickness of single eye").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Diameter of Pin").grid(row=4)
Label(master, text="Diameter of knuckle pin head and collar").grid(row=5)

e1_var = StringVar()
e2_var = StringVar()
e3_var = StringVar()
e4_var = StringVar()
e5_var = StringVar()
e6_var = StringVar()

e1 = Entry(master,textvariable=e1_var)
e2 = Entry(master,textvariable=e2_var)
e3 = Entry(master,textvariable=e3_var)
e4 = Entry(master,textvariable=e4_var)
e5 = Entry(master,textvariable=e5_var)
e6 = Entry(master,textvariable=e6_var)


e1.grid(row=0, column=50)
e2.grid(row=1, column=50)
e3.grid(row=2, column=50)
e4.grid(row=3, column=50)
e5.grid(row=4, column=50)
e6.grid(row=5, column=50)


Button(master, text='ACCEPT', command=calculations).grid(row=10, column=1, 
sticky=W, pady=4)


master.mainloop( )
```

Output: (with shaft diameter as 20)

```
Outer diameter of eye: 40.000000
Thickness of fork: 15.000000
Thickness of single eye: 35.000000
Diameter of pin: 20.000000
Diameter of knuckle pin and collar: 30.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! This worked for me. Could you please tell me how can I print results in the textboxes.

Comment: Modified the code in answer to display in the UI itself. Please upvote answer if it worked for you. Happy Learning!!

Comment: can't upvote getting this "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." sorry

Comment: this was very helpful. Could you tell me how to add image in the GUI at required location. I've used Pil  and pillow and other commands and I've successfully imported the image but it is disturbing other elements of the GUI. I want the image to be in the center and all the text boxes and label should remain aligned as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the exception, you can easily solve it.
You defiend `calculations` function with one input parameter but when you call it you don't pass any parameter to it. Try this code instead of `command=calculations`:

```
command = lambda: calculations(YUOR_INPUT_PARAMETER)
```

For more information [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)