# importError: Cannot import name 'quitprogram' from 'GUIhelperFunction'

Tags: python-3.x, tk-toolkit

I have made 2 py files 'Main' and `GUIHelperFunctions` in the same folder and I want to use the function `quitprogram` from that module in my `main` file, the exact same way as if I just made the function in the `main` file itself. but I am getting an

> 1importError: Cannot import name 'quitprogram' from GUIhelperFunction1.

How do I solve it?

My code in GUIHelperFunctions.py:

```
    def quitProgram():
        root.quit()
```

and in my main.py:

```
    import numpy as np
    import beam as bm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from GUIHelperFunctions import quitProgram
    import tkinter as tk  # tkinter is a GUI implementation Library

    HEIGHT = 480
    WIDTH = 640

    root = tk.TK()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    # Creates a frame where GUI elements are drawn
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.95)

    # Creating variables that are put into the frame GUI (start up)
    myLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Deflection of beam Calculator", bg='yellow')


    quit = tk.Button(root, text="quit", bg='#AFAFAF', command=quitProgram)

    myLabel.pack()
    quit.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Edit 1:

I tried to solve it some more and I return to this `error` even then I make sure that it is written as my post does it. If I put the function from `GUIHelperFunction` into my `main` file, the program freezes.

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\code Assignments\Exam Project\GUIHelperFunctions.py", line 8, in quitProgram
    NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Edit 2:

Okay the freeze was due to using `root.quit()` instead of `root.destroy()`. The above problem is still actual though.

Comment: probably a typo. `GUIhelperFunction` or `GUIHelperFunction` or `GUIhelperFunctions` or `GUIHelperFunctions`?

Comment: No it's not a typo but thanks. The only typo was what I wrote as my comment. Sorry

Comment: you might have cyclical dependencies. can you paste the imports in `GUIHelperFunctions.py`?

Comment: There is none, I now get another error after I restarted the IDE.



Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\code Assignments\Exam Project\GUIHelperFunctions.py", line 8, in quitProgram
NameError: name 'root' is not defined.


Before that It just freezed then I clicked the button. So I'm cycling between these 3 issues with just deleting and writing the same things again.

Comment: The only code at the `GUIHelperFunctions` is the one you added? How can it access the `root` variable if it does not defined or passed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception your problem is not with the `import` of the `quitProgram` function it with the function itself.

> NameError: name 'root' is not defined

When you `import` the function from the different file it does not aware to all the main file variables i.e (in the context of your code) the `root` variable is not defined at the `GUIHelperFunctions` therefor it is not recognized at the `quitProgram` function therefor it can't be used there -> results with the `NameError` exception.

I would suggest the following changes so it would work:

1. Change the signature of the `quitProgram` function:

```
def quitProgram(root):
    root.destroy()
```

2. Call the function with the relevant parameter:

```
quit = tk.Button(root, text="quit", bg='#AFAFAF', command=lambda: quitProgram(root))
```

Please see [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter) for more information and examples.

Comment: By using your changes I get

TypeError: quitProgram() takes 0 positional arguments, but 1 was given

Comment: Yes I did put the "root" as a parameter into the function in the GUIHelperFunctions as specified,
And "lambda: quitProgram(root))" into the button function.

Comment: It works in another IDE then I instead write  command=lambda: GUIHelperFunctions.quitProgram(root). So it's solved then, thanks!