# Python self.attribute cannot be seen when calling class method

Tags: python, class, tkinter, namespaces, attributeerror

I have a problem related to a TKinter GUI I am creating, but the problem is not necessarily specific to this library.

***Background***

I am currently in the advanced stage of a python self-learning course. The learning module I am on is covering TKinter for creating interactive GUI's. I am making a game whereby randomly generated numbered buttons must be clicked in succession in the quickest time possible.

Brief: https://edube.org/learn/pcpp1-4-gui-programming/lab-the-clicker

***Problem***

- Under my class, game_grid, I have created an instance variable; 'self.holder', a 25 entry dictionary of {Key : TkinterButtonObject} form
- When calling this instance variable for use in a class method, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'game_grid' object has no attribute 'holder'`

- I have a print statement under class **init** which proves this attribute has been successfully created. I have made sure my spacing and tabs are all OK, and have tried every location for this variable, including using as a class variable, and a global variable to no avail - as it is an semi-complex object. I don't see what difference it should make, but any ideas would be much appreciated. I am also aware this could be done without classes, but I am trying to adopt DRY principles and orthogonality in all of my programs.

Thanks in advance.

***Full Code:***

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

win   = tk.Tk()

class game_grid:

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.last_number = 0
        self.number_buttons = {}
        self.row_count = 0
        self.column_count = 0
        #Generate a list of 25 random numbers
        self.number_list = random.sample(range(0, 999), 25)
        #Puts the numbers in a dictionary (number : buttonobject)
        self.holder = {i: tk.Button(win, text = str(i), command = game_grid.select_button(self, i)) for i in self.number_list}
        #pack each object into window by iterating rows and columns
        for key in self.holder:
            self.holder[key].grid(column = self.column_count, row = self.row_count)
            if self.column_count < 4:
                self.column_count += 1
            elif self.column_count == 4:
                self.column_count = 0
                self.row_count += 1
        print(self.holder)


    def select_button(self, number):
        if number > self.last_number:
            self.holder[number].config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.last_number = number
        else:
            pass


class stopclock():

    def __init__(self):
        #Stopclock variable initialisation
        self.time_begin  = 0
        self.time_end    = 0
        self.time_elapsed= 0

    def start(self):
        if self.time_begin == 0:
            self.time_begin = time.time()
            return("Timer started\nStart time: ", self.time_begin)
        else:
            return("Timer already active")

    def stop(self):
        self.time_end = time.time()
        self.time_elapsed = time_end - time_begin
        return("Timer finished\nEnd time: ", time_begin,"\nTime Elapsed: ", time_elapsed)       

play1 = game_grid(win)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***AttributeError: 'game_grid' object has no attribute 'holder'***: That's correct, you try to use `self.holder` before it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
command = self.select_button(self, i)
```

**Update:**

Though from research:[How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

It should be:

```
command = lambda i=i: self.select_button(i)
```

Comment: Thanks so much - such a simple edit that now works flawlessly, i can crack on with refining my code.  I now have a more accurate view i now have of how my code is seen and executed which will undoubtedly come in handy again. Also, that i should scrub-up on lambdas!

Answer (score 0):

You call `select_button` from inside the dict comprehension of `holder`. `select_button` then tries to use `holder`, but it is not yet defined.  You don't want to actually call `select_button`, but assign a function to the button, like that:

```
self.holder = {i: tk.Button(window, text=str(i), command=lambda i=i: self.select_button(i)) for i in self.number_list}
```