# TKinter Get name of button from within button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an app with tkinter and I have the following code:

```py
tricks = ['Always Three', 'bhu']

        def trickInstructions(selectedTrick):
            print(selectedTrick)

        def menu():
            for trick in tricks:
                Button(root, text = trick, pady=1, command = lambda: trickInstructions(self.name)).pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

I would like to send the name of the button to the `trickInstructions()` function everytime the button is clicked.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: You might be looking for [a solution like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762215/).

Comment: @metatoaster I don't really understand this answer and if it applies...

Comment: Change `command = lambda: trickInstructions(self.name)` to `command=lambda name=trick: trickInstructions(name)`.

Comment: If you tried the answer I linked the answer is very obvious, because it literally prints out the text of the button being sent via the callback.

Comment: @acw1668 this worked perfectly, if you write this as an answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: Also please read the question and related answers within the thread to get the full background, rather than just glancing at a given answer for less than a minute and say you don't understand - it hints to me that you might not appreciate an actual answer.

Comment: @metatoaster I have limited knowledge of python and tkinter but this seems like a longer than neccessary way of accomplishing what I want. This has been proven by acw1668s single line answer, I appreciate your input but it was not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the text using `lambda` via default value of argument:

```
command=lambda name=trick: trickInstructions(name)
```