# python tkinter entry variable not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me with this error I don't know how to fix this it.

```
from tkinter import *

def get_data():
    target=Entry.get(note)

def show():
    note=Entry(root)
    note.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b2=Button(root,text='view',command=get_data).grid(row=2,column=2)

root=Tk()
root.title("test")
Label(root,text="click").grid(row=1,column=1)
b1=Button(root,text='click',command=show).grid(row=1,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
target=Entry.get(note)
NameError: name 'note' is not defined
```

Comment: Which function are you calling first?

Comment: @Evorage  show then get data

Comment: How sure are you? Your clicking the button and then calling `get_data`???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Evorage first program will display only one button if you click that button it will display next button

Comment: @quamrana Nope it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Ok, see my answer.

Comment: `note` is a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to functions triggered by buttons:

```py
from tkinter import *

def get_data(note):
    target = Entry.get(note)

def show(root):
    note = Entry(root)
    note.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b2 = Button(root, text='view', command=lambda: get_data(note)).grid(row=2, column=2)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("test")
    Label(root,text="click").grid(row=1, column=1)
    b1 = Button(root, text='click', command=lambda: show(root)).grid(row=1, column=2)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've used a `lambda` to make the call with the parameter `note`.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, very, very hard not to use globals....  I thought you were going to show without globals?

Comment: Your code raised `NameError: name 'root' is not defined` on the line `note = Entry(root)` inside `show()` because `root` is a local variable inside `main()`.

Comment: Ok, same fix coming up,,,

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to define note globally, then just lay it out in the function:

```
from tkinter import *
def get_data():
    target=Entry.get(note)
def show():
    note.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b2=Button(root,text='view',command=get_data).grid(row=2,column=2)
root=Tk()
root.title("test")
note=Entry(root)
Label(root,text="click").grid(row=1,column=1)
b1=Button(root,text='click',command=show).grid(row=1,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: @quamrana Not everyone on SO is a professional programmer ... Sometimes we need to bend the rules to allow the hobbyists to get by without knowing OOP.

Comment: Professional/hobbyist? You're still a programmer. Hobbyists probably try harder than professionals. Plus this is not an OOP thing.

Comment: @quamrana Do you have any better suggession ?

Comment: @Novel it does fix my problem. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @quamrana Ok, go on then, add an answer with your non global solution. I expect you will avoid the global root as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Besides I'm not banning globals, its just that there are so many ways of avoiding them.

Comment: @AnirbanSingha it's a "scope" problem. You can't use a variable that you defined inside the function outside the function.

Comment: @Novel will you explain your answer please? I think both both program do exactly same except printing before and after. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @AnirbanSingha the key is that I defined the "note" variable outside of the function. This makes it "global". Therefore you can access it from both functions. In your code you defined it inside a function. When you define something inside a function it's only available to use in the function, unless you pass it out. This is called function "scope". For beginner questions like this try a beginner forum like learnpython.reddit.com where people can explain it better.