# return self.func(*args) TypeError: serchongoogle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'choice'

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

window = Tk()

e = Entry(window, width=50, borderwidth=5)
e.pack()
choice = e.get()

def serchongoogle(choice):
    if "Cerca" in choice or "cerca" in choice:
        googleUrl = 'http://www.google.com/?#q='
        choice = choice[6:]
        webbrowser.open_new(googleUrl + choice)

button1 = Button(window, text="Click me!", command=serchongoogle)
button1.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

But, when i click on the button, i get this error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: serchongoogle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'choice'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: As the error shows, the function doesn't get its only argument `choice`. This is because the button's `command` is being called without arguments...

Comment: so what should I change?

Comment: Please see the link for many suggestions. For one, try to change `command=lambda: serchongoogle(choice)`

Comment: it doesn't work...