# How to pass argument to function while binding it to a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I have a simple program that makes two password boxes and two buttons that should show and unshow the text in their respective entry boxes.
This is my current code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_stars(event):
    password.config(show="*")

def show_chars(event):
    password.config(show="")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Password")
password = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
password2 = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
password.grid(row=0, column=1)
password2.grid(row=1, column=1)
password_label = tk.Label(text="Confirm Password:")
password_label.grid(row = 1, column=0)
password_label = tk.Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row = 0, column=0)
button = tk.Button(text = '.')
button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", show_chars)
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", show_stars)
button.grid(row=0, column=2)
button2 = tk.Button(text = '.')
button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", show_chars)
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", show_stars)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

I want to make it so that I can pass an argument to the `show_chars` and `show_stars` function like this:

```
def show_stars(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show="*")

def show_chars(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show="")

button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", show_chars(password))
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", show_stars(password))
button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", show_chars(password2))
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", show_stars(password2))
```

So that it does not show and unshow the same entry box. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Try: `button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: show_chars(password))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def show_stars(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show="*")

def show_chars(entry_box):
    entry_box.config(show="")


root = tk.Tk()

password = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Show password")
password2 = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Show password")

password.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=1, column=2)
password2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button2.grid(row=2, column=2)

button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: show_chars(password))
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: show_stars(password))
button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: show_chars(password2))
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: show_stars(password2))

root.mainloop()
```

For more info on how to use `lambda` in python read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

You can also use `functools.partial`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def show_stars(entry_box, event):
    entry_box.config(show="*")

def show_chars(entry_box, event):
    entry_box.config(show="")


root = tk.Tk()

password = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Show password")
password2 = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Show password")

password.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=1, column=2)
password2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button2.grid(row=2, column=2)

command = partial(show_chars, password)
button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", command)
command = partial(show_stars, password)
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", command)

command = partial(show_chars, password2)
button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", command)
command = partial(show_stars, password2)
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", command)

root.mainloop()
```

For more info on `functools.partial` read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: Why did you put `event` after lambda? In an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter) they didn't put anything after lambda.

Comment: Because tkinter always passes an event parameter when the function is called. And 'lambda's are basically function where the things before the `:` are the parameters.

Comment: @Manav You can avoid that, but instead you will have to define a parameter `event` or something.