# Python: Pass variable from one function to another (button pressed)

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I want to make Button2 do something, but only if Button1 has been pressed first and it's code was successfully run.
Also: Button2 should not execute button_1's function, and I do not want to use global variables.

The code below was my initial thought, and it did not work. I've searched for the right way, but neither of the methods I found gave me the result I hoped for.

**Can anyone tell me how to correct this?** I'm also open for easier or better ways to achieve my goal.

```
import tkinter as tk
from sys import exit

window = tk.Tk()

def button_1():
    print("Button 1 pressed")
    button_1_pressed = "Yes"
    return button_1_pressed

def button_2():
    if (button_1_pressed == "Yes"):
        print("Button 1 was pressed, taking action")
        # Action goes here
    else :
        print("Button 1 was NOT pressed, no action is done")

btn_1 = tk.Button(master=window, text="Button 1", width=10, height=2, command=button_1)
btn_1.pack()

btn_2 = tk.Button(master=window, text="Button 2", width=10, height=2, command=button_2)
btn_2.pack()

btn_Close = tk.Button(master=window, text="Close", width=10, height=2, command=exit)
btn_Close.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Note: This is just a quick and simple script, illustrating exactly what I need help with in all simplicity.

Comment: The natural way to do this is to have `Button_1` call `Button_2`.  The ugly way is to use a global variable and a check loop.  You seem to have a [XY Problem]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- you'll need to explain these artificial restrictions.

Comment: You've already got global variables in the form of the `btn_X` variables. You could use those.

Comment: @Prune XY explained:
User will input number in input field
Button1 will run a SQL SELECT and dispaly the values to the user (Verification).
Button2 will run a SQL UPDATE command, but I want to force the user to press Button1 first, so that he verifies that the displayed information is indeed the desired data he want's to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to pass variable from one function to another (button pressed)**

To get returned value from the callback you should use `invoke()` method of the Button.

BUT **it's just returned value**, and unfortunately you cannot use it as a flag, as it doesn't track was the button pressed or not.

So the trick is to create your custom button with a flag which will be changed to `True` by callback and pass the flag as an argument to the `button_2`, to do so you can use `lambda` or `partial` func.

I hope it's fine for you, despite of it uses the vars out of function scope.

**Updated code**:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from sys import exit

window = tk.Tk()


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    pressed = False


def button_1():
    print("Button 1 pressed")
    button_1_pressed = "Yes"
    btn_1.pressed = True
    return button_1_pressed


btn_1 = MyButton(master=window, text="Button 1", width=10, height=2, command=button_1)
btn_1.pack()


def button_2(state):
    if state:
        print("Button 1 was pressed, taking action")
        print('gotcha!')
    else:
        print("Button 1 was NOT pressed, no action is done")


btn_2 = tk.Button(master=window, text="Button 2", width=10, height=2, command=lambda: button_2(btn_1.pressed))
btn_2.pack()

btn_Close = tk.Button(master=window, text="Close", width=10, height=2, command=exit)
btn_Close.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Useful links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

[How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: Thanks @viacheslav-khvorostianyi it works perfect! Can I ask you to explain the "state" part? I did not quite understand it, and I want to understand every line of code in the programs I write. Maybe provide a link to a useful article?

Comment: Glad to be helpful) `state` is just an argument of a callback function, you can named whatever you want, the thing is - if you want to use callbacks with arguments you should use a wrapper for the function. The simplest wrapper is `lambda`. So basically - that's it)