# Refer to a variable inside another function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The intention is to have a user choose a file via

```
select_file_en
```

which will then be encrypted via

```
encrypt
```

I want the program to save the filename of the chosen file in a variable, which can be accessed by the encryption part.
I'm a newbie so please bare with me if this is easy to fix.
Code can be found at https://github.com/KDropZ/NDA/blob/main/main.py and is by far not final at all.
When I run the encrypt part I get the following Error, so my way to "call" the variable seems to be wrong I guess?

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args) TypeError: encrypt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

Additional info: Python 3.8.10, Tkinter 8.6, Ubuntu OS

Code example

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import os

def select_file_en():
    filetypes = (
        ('All files', '*.*'),       
        )

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Choose a file to encrypt',
        initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)

    showinfo(
        title='Selected File',
        message=filename
        )

def encrypt(filename):
    to_encrypt = open(filename, "rb").read()
    size = len(to_encrypt)
    key = os.urandom(size)
    with open(filename + ".key", "wb") as key_out:
        key_out.write(key)
        encrypted = bytes(a^b for (a,b) in zip(filename, key))
    with open(filename, "wb") as encrypted_out:
        encrypted_out.write(encrypted)
```

Comment: Use a global variable. Assign the global variable in `select_file_en`, and use it in `encrypt`

Comment: Every class member function must have one positional parameter, typically called `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in line 127:

```
tk.Button(root, cursor='hand2', text='Encrypt file', font=buttonFont, bg='#FF6D6D', fg='#ffffff', command=encrypt).place(anchor='nw', relx='0.78', rely='0.12', x='0', y='0')
```

You call the `encrypt(filename)` function on a button click (`command=encrypt`), but you do not provide the filename! This is also what your error message says: `missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'`.

You need to find a way to provide the function in the tkinter button with a variable: [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

basically, you need to *save* the filename that is chosen in `select_file_en()` to a variable (lets call it `my_filename`), and then use a [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function (ELI5: a small function, often used in another function) to pass the variable in the command used in the tkinter button:

```
command= lambda: encrypt(my_filename)
```