# GUI for a random password generator

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning to use tkinter and ttk so I tried making a GUI for a random password generator and this is my code so far:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


win = Tk()

win.geometry("300x250")
win.title('random pass generator')


global password_length
password_length = int()


enter_length = ttk.Entry(win , textvariable = password_length)
enter_length.pack()

global password
password = StringVar()


def generate_password(password_length):
    i = 0
    characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    while i < password_length:
        password = password + random.choice(characters)
        i = i + 1

generate = ttk.Button(win,text = 'generate',command = generate_password(password_length))
generate.pack()

label = ttk.Label(win,textvariable = password)
label.config(background = 'black')
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

The problem is that it doesn't give me the password after I write the password's length and click the button.

I tried to assign the password to a label to get it on screen but it doesn't show up after I click the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: StringVar value should be changed with the set() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have `password` as a `StringVar`, you need to use the `set` method to assign it a value, e.g.,:

```py
password.set(password.get() + random.choice(characters))
```

rather than:

```py
password = password + random.choice(characters)
```

Also, the `command` argument to `Button` can only take a function handle rather than a call to a function, i.e., you could only pass `command=generate_password` and not `command=generate_password(password_length)`. You can either make `password_length` global rather than being an argument to the function, hardcode it into the function, or use a lambda function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921225/1862861)), like:

```py
generate = ttk.Button(
    win,
    text='generate',
    command=lambda: generate_password(password_length)
)
```

Finally, if using the `lambda` option above, you should also change:

```py
password_length = int()
enter_length = ttk.Entry(win , textvariable = password_length)
```

to

```py
password_length = StringVar()
enter_length = ttk.Entry(win, textvariable=password_length)
```

as `textvariable` should take a `StringVar` rather than an `int`. And then within `generate_password`, have:

```py
while i < int(password_length.get()):
```

So, overall the code will be:

```py
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


win = Tk()

win.geometry("300x250")
win.title('random pass generator')


password_length = StringVar()
enter_length = ttk.Entry(win, textvariable=password_length)
enter_length.pack()

password = StringVar()

def generate_password(password_length):
    i = 0
    characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    while i < int(password_length.get()):
        password.set(password.get() + random.choice(characters))
        i = i + 1

generate = ttk.Button(
    win,
    text='generate',
    command=lambda: generate_password(password_length)
)
generate.pack()

label = ttk.Label(win,textvariable = password)
label.config(background='black')
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Noting that, by setting the `label` background to black you won't be able see the password text as it will also be black.

Comment: You might want to point out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920302/11106801) problem as well.