# How to display something after an Entry widget is filled in another area of the GUI?

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, widget

I'm building a GUI to write to an excel spreadsheet. However, before I do the writing to spreadsheet, the user will input data in the GUI. What I want to do is when the user puts in a release number in the first entry and "tab" to the next entry, I want the date to automatically populate.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Truck Log Entry Form")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

#saving truck logs
truck_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Truck Information")
truck_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

release_number_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Release Number")
release_number_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
truck_name_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Truck Name")
truck_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
tare_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Tare Weight")
tare_info_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
date_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Date/Time")
date_info_label.grid(row=0, column=3)
gross_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text = "Gross Weight")
gross_info_label.grid(row=0, column=4)


date_info_result_str = tkinter.StringVar()

release_number_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame, textvariable=date_info_result_str)
truck_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame)
tare_info_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame)
#date_info_result = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text='')
date_info_result = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame)
date_info_result.grid(row=1, column=3)
date_info_result_str.trace('w', lambda *args: auto_date(release_number_entry.get()) )
release_number_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
truck_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
tare_info_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)


for widget in truck_info_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

def auto_date(release_filled):

    print("in auto_date function " + release_filled)
    #release_filled = release_number_entry.get()

    if len(release_filled) >= 6:
        print("in len area")
        #datetime object containing current date and time
        now = datetime.now()

        #format date and time to dd/mm/YY H:M:S
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        return dt_string
    else:
        print("made in error")
        #tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Error", message="Please check release number")

window.mainloop()
```

I created a function for it to be called then tried to do a .trace method but that doesn't seem to work. Furthermore, I tried messing around with validate but it only returns true or false and I'm not sure how to get that and I suppose call another function to display the time under the data_info_label. I would appreciate any help on this.

Update (1/12/23): I was able to call on the function and get it to trace successfully but how do I return the date and time from the function into the label?

Comment: There are 2 problems with `.trace('1', auto_date(...) )`. First of all, the first parameter of `.trace` should be `"w"`. Second, it should be `lambda: auto_date(...)` instead of just `auto_date(...)` - look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920302/11106801) for more info.

Comment: So I modified it to what you suggested but now it's not even calling on the function anymore and I looked at the link you gave me. This is for a button and I do not want a button as a cause-and-effect but rather when I tab out of the entry box to go to the next entry box. 

However, this is a good start but for some reason, it's not calling on the function after I tab out.

Comment: The question I linked had the same problem, when `tkinter` expects a function, you can't call the function beforehand. In both cases, instead of `auto_date(...)` you need `lambda: auto_date(...)`. Also `date_info_result_str` isn't linked to anything. Please look at some `tkinter` tutorials.

Comment: I'm not trying to call it beforehand. I'm trying to call it after the "Release Number" box is filled so I can auto-populate the date/time label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is when the user puts in a release number in the first entry and "tab" to the next entry, I want the date to automatically populate.

If you want to do something when the user presses the tab key,  you can bind a function to the event `<Tab>`. You don't want to do it on a trace associated with a stringvar since that would be called every time the user inserts or deletes a single character.

Here's a very simple example showing one way to do it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

def insert_date(entry):
    now = datetime.now()
    label.configure(text=now.strftime("%c"))

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
label = tk.Label(root)
entry.pack(side="top")
label.pack(side="top")

entry.bind("<Tab>", lambda event: insert_date(label))

root.mainloop()
```

When you run the above example and press the tab key while the first entry has keyboard focus, it will insert the date and time into the second entry.

Comment: This helps a ton!! Now, if I don't want to modify an entry box, could I use .setvar to modify the label (date_info_result) with the date/time result?

Comment: @CptLuna: you can do anything you want in the callback. I apologize for not reading the question closely enough. I've updated the example to modify a label rather than insert the data into an entry.

Comment: oh no problem, I didn't see your response but figured it out by using the configue but you definitely did it differently than I did. Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Brian Oakley, I was able to figure out the rest! Huge help and here's the code below to see how I did it.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Truck Log Entry Form")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

#saving truck logs
truck_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Truck Information")
truck_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

release_number_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Release Number")
release_number_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
truck_name_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Truck Name")
truck_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
tare_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Tare Weight")
tare_info_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
date_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text="Date/Time")
date_info_label.grid(row=0, column=3)
gross_info_label = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text = "Gross Weight")
gross_info_label.grid(row=0, column=4)


#date_info_result_str = tkinter.StringVar()

#release_number_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame, textvariable=date_info_result_str)
release_number_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame)
truck_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame)
tare_info_entry = tkinter.Entry(truck_info_frame)
#date_info_result = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame, text='')
date_info_result = tkinter.Label(truck_info_frame)
date_info_result.grid(row=1, column=3)
#date_info_result_str.trace('w', lambda *args: auto_date(release_number_entry.get()) )
release_number_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
truck_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
tare_info_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

release_number_entry.bind("<Tab>", lambda event: auto_date(release_number_entry.get()))


for widget in truck_info_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

def auto_date(release_filled):

    print("in auto_date function " + release_filled)
    #release_filled = release_number_entry.get()

    if len(release_filled) >= 6:
        print("in len area")
        #datetime object containing current date and time
        now = datetime.now()

        #format date and time to dd/mm/YY H:M:S
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        date_info_result.config(text = dt_string)
    else:
        print("made in error")
        #tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Error", message="Please check release number")

window.mainloop()
```