# Insert the same text in differents entry widget with same button is clicked Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I want to create a button in tkinter that prints text in different `Entry` depends if it clicked. The text to be displayed must be the same, but not at the same time.

I have this code to try to get the result:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
event = StringVar()


def callback(event):
    print("focus in event raised, open keyboard")
    return event

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.pack()

addressInput = Entry(frame, font = "Verdana 20 ", justify="center")
addressInput.bind("<FocusIn>", callback)
addressInput.pack()
addressInput.focus_set()

otroInput = Entry(frame, font = "Verdana 20 ", justify="center")
otroInput.bind("<FocusIn>", callback)
otroInput.pack()


def inserta(text):
    if event == ".!frame.!entry":
        addressInput.insert(200,text)
    if event == ".!frame.!entry2":
        otroInput.insert(200,text)


inserta=Button(frame, text="Insert number 2 ", command=inserta("2"))
inserta.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So when I click `inserta(Buttom)` in `addressInput(entry)` you can see the number "2". If you select `otroInput(Entry)` and then click the Button, you see number "2" in `otroInput(Entry)`.

If you have any suggestions, I would be very grateful, please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just so I understand what you're asking: You want to set the text of the `Entry` widget that currently has focus when the user presses a `Button`? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! That's correct

Comment: I suggest you read [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)

Comment: I tried to pass arguments to a Button command, but the text is only set in one Entry

Comment: @Une Are you trying to set the text for both `Entry` widgets at once, or just the one that has focus? I should also point out that either `Entry` will lose focus once you click the button, so you'd have to keep track of which widget had focus just before the button was pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to be inserted into the widget with keyboard focus, you can use `focus_get()` to get the widget with the focus. You can then check to see if it's an entry widget, and insert text into it if it is.

```
def inserta():
    focus = root.focus_get()
    if focus and focus.winfo_class() == "Entry":
        focus.insert("insert", "a")
...
inserta=Button(frame, text="Insert number 2 ", command=inserta)
```

If you want to be able to pass in what is to be inserted, you can use `lambda` to create an anonymous function:

```
def do_insert(char):
    focus = root.focus_get()
    if focus and focus.winfo_class() == "Entry":
        focus.insert("insert", char)
...
insert2=Button(frame, text="Insert number 2 ", command=lambda: do_insert("2")
```

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. How about walrus? Would it nice like this?     def inserta():
        if [focus := root.focus_get()]and focus.winfo_class() == "Entry":
            focus.insert("insert", "a")