# Is there an option to use user input besides print it in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, input, python-dataclasses

First off, I am new to Python and new to programming. but I am trying to make a program that puts together a database with user input. In this particular example, I am trying to take a date from user input and add it to a dataclass

here is the relevant code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import tkcalendar
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Route Cards")

def enter_data():
    date = date_entry.get()
    print(date)

def date_entry ():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

top = tk.Toplevel(window)

    cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',             locale='en_US',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2024, month=1, day=26)

    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

date = ttk.Button(customer_info_frame, text='date', command=cal_select)
date.grid(row=7, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

the date box opens a window and when the user selects the date and chooses ok it prints. but I want to take that date and add it to the function enter_data so I can add it to a dataclass as a str (or a datetime)

but all I can do is print it in the terminal. I have tried Return but it just returns "None"

The answer to this particular problem would be helpful but i just need help in general on how to get a user input() and put that information elsewhere. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I got this particular code to work with quite a bit of re writing, but the main question stands. Maybe the problem I am having is with taking input from a function and using it? Like I said, I am new, so I'm not really sure what the problem is. But is there a way to take a string from input from one function and use it in another function?

Comment: Are you sure this code runs?  `print_sel()` is defined as a subfunction inside of `date_entry()`, so it wouldn't be visible in the button call.

Comment: You seem to struggle with the concept of functions and how to connect them to actions in TKinter. You have three functions that are never called, but on the other hand there are two `command`s that connect to non-existing functions. (`print_sel` will never be created in this code)

Comment: no, The code does not run like this. That is the problem, I am trying to figure out how to get the input from date_entry to enter_data

Comment: This is not the complete code, only the relevant part to the question.  I need to figure out how to get the input from date_entry() to enter_data()

Comment: Why are you suing on fly `window = tk.Tk()` and `top = tk.Toplevel(window)`?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I'm not sure I know what you mean by suing. I think you mean tk.tk (why the two tk's) the short answer is ignorance. I watched a tutorial and that is what they did. I see now that it doesn't have to be there. that is the problem with learning from youtube. Picking up other people's bad habits. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry using not suing. It is misspelled.

Comment: `date_entry.get()` doesn't make sense. `date_entry` isn't the calendar widget, it's a function. Did you mean `cal.get()`?

Comment: The indentation of the lines from `cal =` to `ttk.Button()` is wrong.

Comment: line 27, in <module>
    date = ttk.Button(customer_info_frame, text='date', command=cal_select)
NameError: name 'customer_info_frame' is not defined

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!toplevel which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: Change this `date.grid(row=7, column=1)` to `date.pack()`, So, you can see two Button widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the most common solutions are: passing the values of local variables using a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lambda) or using a global [textvariable](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry).

*See also: [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)*

#### Using a lambda to get a value from an input field.

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar


def enter_data():
    print("Enter data:")
    try:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_entry.get(), "%m/%d/%Y")
        print(datetime_obj)
        print("entry value:", date_entry.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date")

    
def get_locals(top_widget, cal_value, formated_date):
    """
    top_widget: <class 'tkinter.Toplevel'>
    cal_value:  <class 'datetime.date'>
    formated_date: <class 'str'>
    """
    date_entry.delete(0, "end")
    date_entry.insert(0, formated_date) 
    top_widget.withdraw()
    print("Get locals:", "\ncal_value:", cal_value, "\nformated_date:", formated_date)

    
def demo(text):
    top = tk.Toplevel(window, name="top") # one at a time
    x = window.winfo_x()
    y = window.winfo_y() 
    top.geometry(f"+{x + 100}+{y + 100}")
    top.title(text)
    cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   locale='en_US', cursor="hand1",
                   date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    # using a lambda to delay the execution of a function until a button is clicked
    # pass locals to another function
    top_button = ttk.Button(top, text="ok",
                            command=lambda: get_locals(top, cal.selection_get(), cal.get_date()))
    top_button.pack()
    print("Demo locals:\n", locals().keys())

    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Route Cards")

date_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
date_entry.pack()
date_entry.insert(0, "01/30/2024")
                  
demo_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Demo", command=lambda: demo("Calendar"))
demo_button.pack()

submit_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Submit form", command=enter_data)
submit_button.pack()

# these names are available in functions
print("Globals:")
print(globals().keys())

window.mainloop()
```

#### Using a textvariable to get or set the value of an input field.

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar


def enter_data():
    print("Enter data:")
    print("textvariable:", date_textvariable.get())
    try:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_entry.get(), "%m/%d/%Y")
        print(datetime_obj)
        print("entry value:", date_entry.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date")

    
def demo(text):
    top = tk.Toplevel(window, name="top") # one at a time
    x = window.winfo_x()
    y = window.winfo_y() 
    top.geometry(f"+{x + 100}+{y + 100}")
    top.title(text)
    cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   locale='en_US', cursor="hand1",
                   date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    # change entry value
    top_button = ttk.Button(top, text="ok",
                            command=lambda: [date_textvariable.set(cal.get_date()), top.withdraw()])
    top_button.pack()

    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Route Cards")

date_textvariable = tk.StringVar()
print("empty:", date_textvariable.get())
date_textvariable.set("01/30/2024")
print("initial value:", date_textvariable.get())

date_entry = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=date_textvariable)
date_entry.pack()

demo_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Demo", command=lambda: demo("Calendar"))
demo_button.pack()

submit_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Submit form", command=enter_data)
submit_button.pack()

# these names are available in functions
print("Globals:")
print(globals().keys())

window.mainloop()

print("Var:", date_textvariable.get())
```