# Tkinter binding a function with arguments to a widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter frame and a button attached to it:

```
from tkinter import *

def rand_func(a,b,c,effects):
    print (a+b+c)

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.bind("<Return>",lambda a=10, b=20, c=30: rand_func(a,b,c))
frame.pack()

button=Button(frame, text="click me", command=lambda a=1,b=2,c=3,eff=None:rand_func(a,b,c))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want the same function to be done when user presses enter and when he presses the button. Sadly, the code above gives an error at the frame binding. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you create a binding with `bind`, Tkinter automatically adds an argument that has information about the event. You'll need to account for that either in your `rand_func` definition or in how you call it.

This argument is *not* included when you use the `command` attribute. You must take care to account for this extra argument either in how you call the function in each case, or in how the function interprets its parameters.

Here's one solution that uses `lambda` in the binding to accept the extra event only when using `bind` command, but not pass it on to the final command.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="click me",
                             command=lambda a=1, b=2, c=3: 
                                self.rand_func(a, b, c))
        self.button.pack()
        self.frame.bind("<Return>", 
                        lambda event, a=10, b=20, c=30: 
                            self.rand_func(a, b, c))
        # make sure the frame has focus so the binding will work
        self.frame.focus_set()

    def rand_func(self, a, b, c):
        print "self:", self, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c
        print (a+b+c)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

That being said, it's rare that binding to a frame is the right thing to do. Typically a frame won't have keyboard focus, and unless it has focus the binding will never fire. If you are setting a global binding you should either bind to the "all" binding tag (using the [bind_all](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind_all-method) method) or to the toplevel widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as you suggested bind_all was what I needed;

Comment: It's important to note that the _automatically adds an argument that has information about the event_ applies only to callbacks bound by `bind` method. Those bound with `command` option (in constructor or with `configure()`) don't receive such event object. This distinction isn't easy to spot in the docs (at least I haven't found any), but here's [confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726716/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-bind-in-tkinter)

Comment: @o'rety: I've updated the answer to address your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
import tkinter as tk


def rand_func(eff=None, a=1, b=2, c=3):
    print(a + b + c)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Return>", lambda eff: rand_func(eff, a=10, b=20, c=30))

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="click me",
                   command=lambda: rand_func(None, 1, 2, 3))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Forgot to write in the code that the arguments are different, editing question

Comment: This solution did the trick for me. Simple and easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: whats the use of eff?