# Bind a tkinter widget to a function containing args - Use of Lambda

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

There is a list :

```
liste_physical_activity.insert(1, pa1)
liste_physical_activity.insert(2, pa2)
liste_physical_activity.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',  CurSelet_physical_activity)
liste_physical_activity.pack()
```

Linked to the following function :

```
def CurSelet_physical_activity(event, window_mother):
     # stuff
```

Even with using lambda it doesn't work:

```
<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event, 
window_mother=main_window  CurSelet_physical_activity (event, window_mother))
```

The problem is that the `main_window` has been created in another `file.py`, so he doesn't know it.

How can i fix this ?

EDIT for the ref problem :

**main.py**

```
from Energy_Requirement import*
main_window =Tk()
bouton_energy_requirement= Button(main_window, text="Estimation of energy requirement", command=lambda:energy_requirement(main_window))
bouton_energy_requirement.pack()
```

**file1.py**

```
def energy_requirement(window_mother):
    pa1="NRC"
    pa2="Kornfeld"     
    window5=Toplevel(window_mother)
    liste_physical_activity = Listbox(window5,width=80, height=5)
    liste_physical_activity.insert(1, pa1)
    liste_physical_activity.insert(2, pa2)
    liste_physical_activity.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',  CurSelet_physical_activity)
    liste_physical_activity.pack()

def CurSelet_physical_activity(event):
    global liste_physical_activity
    value=str(liste_physical_activity.get(liste_physical_activity.curselection()))

    if value==pa1:
       ER=1
       label = Label(main_window, text="Energy Requirement (kcal ME/day)")
       label.pack()
       show_ER=StringVar()
       show_ER.set(ER)
       entree_ER = Entry(main_window,textvariable=show_ER,width=30)
       entree_ER.pack()


    if value==pa2:
       ER=2
       label = Label(main_window, text=" Energy Requirement (kcal ME/day)")
       label.pack()
       show_ER=StringVar()
       show_ER.set(ER)
       entree_ER = Entry(main_window,textvariable=show_ER,width=30)
       entree_ER.pack()
```

Comment: That use of lambda doesn't look like valid python. is that your actual code?

Comment: I don't use it since it doesn't work and return "main window is not defined" but i tried to adapt from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299955/tkinter-binding-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-widget

Comment: Withouts seeing actual code, it's impossible to guess how to fix it. Please provide a complete, minimal example that illustrates the problem. Don't include all your code, create the _smallest_ working program possible that gives the same error.

Comment: Edited again. Hope this could help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`energy_requirement` is being passed a reference to `main_window`, so all you need to do is pass that value along in the binding. This should work:

```
def energy_requirement(window_mother):
    ...
    liste_physical_activity.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',  
        lambda event, mw=window_mother: CurSelet_physical_activity(event, mw))
```

You'll then need to modify `CurSelet_physical_activity` to accept this additional parameter:

```
def CurSelet_physical_activity(event, main_window):
    ...

    if value==pa1:
       ER=1
       label = Label(main_window, text="Energy Requirement (kcal ME/day)")
       ...
```

It doesn't look like you use `event` anywhere in `CurSelet_physical_activity`, so you can remove that from the binding and from the parameter list of the function if you want.

Comment: Thanks. Understood for the use of the lambda. I edit my post to explain this main window problem. :o

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, doesn't work : "    liste_physical_activity.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',  lambda event, mw=main_window: CurSelet_physical_activity(event, mw))
NameError: name 'main_window' is not defined
"

Comment: @BoobaGump: my apologies. I failed to recognize you call it `window_mother` in `energy_requirement`. Change it in the binding and it will work. I will update the answer.