# How to pass two or more arguments to a Button command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to pass 2 variable arguments in a function to be assigned to a `Button` `command`. These variables change within a `for` loop that also creates the buttons.

Mostly inspired by some of the top answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared/47980499#47980499) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter/47996979#47996979), here are my fail attempts at trying to solve this problem based on what I read:

I tried using `partial`:

```py
self.dct[(i, j)] = Button(command=partial(self.on_click, i, j))
```

Another try:

```py
self.dct[(i, j)] = Button(command=partial(partial(self.on_click, i), j))
```

And another:

```py
self.dct[(i, j)] = Button(command=partial(self.on_click, [i, j]))
```

.. Guess what?

```py
tup = [i, j]
self.dct[(i, j)] = Button(command=partial(self.on_click, tup))
```

And then, `lambda`:

```py
self.dct[(i, j)] = Button(command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i, j))
```

Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

from functools import partial


class Board(tk.Frame):
    board = None
    images = None
    tile = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.tile = {}
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                self.tile[(i, j)]['btn_obj'] = tk.Button(self.board, command=partial(partial(self.on_click, i), j))

    def on_click(self, i, j):
        print("X: {}, Y:{}".format(j, i))
```

`partial` always causes an error like this:

```py
TypeError: on_click() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

It's always mismatched number of arguments.

Meanwhile, `lambda` gets the wrong value of the variables, causing something of an error in `tkinter`'s part.

Comment: Why do you think the `lambda` doesn't work? It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda in your question should work:

```
tk.Button(self.board, command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i,j))
```

This binds the value `i` and `j` as the default values for the lambda parameters.

Personally I prefer lambda over partial, mainly because I don't have to import the functools module. If you wish to use partial, it should look like your first example:

```
tk.Button(self, command=partial(self.on_click, i, j))
```

In both cases, `on_click` will be passed the correct value for `i` and `j` based on their values when the button is created.

Here is an example based on your code, but with some unnecessary code removed for clarity:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


class Board(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, method):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bd=2, relief="sunken")
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                if method == "lambda":
                    button = tk.Button(self, command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i,j))
                else:
                    button = tk.Button(self, command=partial(self.on_click, i, j))
                button.grid(row=i, column=j)

    def on_click(self, i, j):
        print("X: {}, Y:{}".format(j, i))

root = tk.Tk()
board1 = Board(root, method="lambda")
board2 = Board(root, method="partial")
board1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
board2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I do this with the `bind()` method? I did something like this: `button.bind("<Enter>", partial(self.on_enter, i, j))` but this error shows up again: `TypeError: on_enter() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Comment: @mashedpotatoes: that's a different question, but the technique is precisely the same. You simply have to account for the extra argument sent by tkinter. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28996754/7432