# What is the difference between command and bind in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, methods, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button print a string when it's pressed and print another when it's released. I know about the `command` atribute and the `bind` method, but I would like to know if it's possible to accomplish it only using atributes or if I have to use methods. With this piece of code:

```
class motor:
     def __init__(eleMesmo, eixo , valorZero):
         eleMesmo.eixo = eixo
         eleMesmo.zero = valorZero

     def aumenta(self):
         print(self.eixo + str(self.zero+5))
     def diminui(self):
         print(self.eixo + str(self.zero-5))
     def para(self):
    print(self.eixo + str(self.zero))

eixox = motor('x',90)
eixoy = motor('y',90)


class Interface:
    def __init__(elemesmo, widget):
         quadro = Frame(widget)
         quadro.pack()
         elemesmo.aumentarY = Button(quadro,text="Aumentar Y",height=10,width=20,command=eixoy.aumenta)
         elemesmo.aumentarY.pack(side=TOP)
         elemesmo.diminuirY = Button(quadro,text="Diminuir Y",height=10,width=20,command=eixoy.diminui)
```

I can call the method `aumenta` for object `eixo y` when button `aumentarY` is pressed. I would like to call the method `para` for object `eixo y` when button `aumentarY` is released. How I can do it?

Comment: command is only for "click on button" and receives no arguments. Any widget can have bindings for a bunch of different kinds of events and will always pass an `Event` object as the one and only argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All [Event types are outlined here](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/event-types.html), you are looking for `<Button-1>` (click down on button 1 (left mouse button if you are right handed))  and `<ButtonRelease-1>` (release mouse button 1 (left button if you are right handed)).

Note I wouldn't use `command` if you bind both of these.

```
 elemesmo.aumentarY = Button(quadro,text="Aumentar Y",height=10,width=20)
 elemesmo.aumentarY.bind("<Button-1>",eixoy.aumenta)
 elemesmo.aumentarY.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",eixoy.para)
```

However you must know that when using `bind` the callback is called with an [Event](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/event-handlers.html) object, if you don't need it you can just add an optional and unused parameter to the callback:

```
 def aumenta(self, event=None):
     print(self.eixo + str(self.zero+5))
 def diminui(self, event=None):
     print(self.eixo + str(self.zero-5))
 def para(self, event=None):
    print(self.eixo + str(self.zero))
```

Answer (score 2):

Both **command** and **.bind** method are used to add life and functionality to a button, using the **tkinter** module on Python.

**Command Parameter**:

```
tkinter.Button(frame, text="Exit", fg="green", bg="pink", command=master.destroy)
```

The above button would destroy the frame we the 'Exit' button is selected or clicked any how. Try using the *tab* key and pressing *spacebar*. You will notice that the button would work. 
What if you don't want that? 
What if you strictly want the user to click it using the left mouse button?
Note that, you can pass a simple zero-parameter method to the *command* parameter, which may or may not contain any event object.

**Bind Method**:

The bind method is used to add extra information/functionality to the button, the way it needs to be clicked, the specific button that needs to be used and so on. It looks something like this:

```
btn = Button(frame, text="Exit", fg="green", bg="pink")
btn.bind(sequence="<Button-1>", func=master.destroy)
```

This will work only when the Mouse Button-1 (Left-Mouse Button) is *pressed*. Some alternate versions to this are like:

```
btn.bind(sequence="<ButtonRelease-1>", func=master.destroy)
```

The above works when the Mouse Button-1 is *pressed and released*.

```
btn.bind(sequence="<Double-Button-1>", func=master.destroy)
```

Similarly, the above sequence works only when the Mouse Button-1 is *Double Clicked*.

Note that, in the bind method you cannot pass a simple zero-parameter method to the *bind* method, it must contain one event object as shown below.

```
def callback(event):
          pass
```

*For the entire list of sequences for bind method, refer [this](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php) article.*