# Python Get the Selected Radio Button's Text/label Name and not just the Value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to print not just the Value of the radio button but also it's Name.
so that I can do this "You selected 'Radio 2' with Value of '23' "

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.var = StringVar()
    self.var.set("Cat")
    radio1 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio1", value="Cat")
    radio1.bind('<Double-1>', lambda :self.show_radioname("radio1"))
    radio1.pack()
    radio2 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio2", value="Dog")
    radio2.bind('<Double-1>', lambda :self.show_radioname("radio2"))
    radio2.pack()
    radio3 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio3", value="Horse")
    radio3.bind('<Double-1>', lambda :self.show_radioname("radio3"))
    radio3.pack()

    submit_button = Button(self.master, text="print",  command=self.show_var)
    submit_button.pack()

def show_var(self):
    print(self.var.get())

@staticmethod
def show_radioname(radio_name):
    print(radio_name)
```

I can get the Value of The Radio But could not get their Text Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a binding with `bind`, Tkinter automatically adds an argument that has information about the event. You must take care to account for this extra argument. (Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299955/tkinter-binding-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-widget#7301218))

So, if you are using `lambda`, you can just add a parameter to it, like this :

`lambda event: self.show_radioname("radio1"))`

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set("Cat")
        radio1 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio1", value="Cat")
        radio1.bind('<Double-1>', lambda event: self.show_radioname("radio1"))
        radio1.pack()
        radio2 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio2", value="Dog")
        radio2.bind('<Double-1>', lambda event: self.show_radioname("radio2"))
        radio2.pack()
        radio3 = Radiobutton(self.master, variable=self.var, text="radio3", value="Horse")
        radio3.bind('<Double-1>', lambda event: self.show_radioname("radio3"))
        radio3.pack()

        submit_button = Button(self.master, text="print",  command=self.show_var)
        submit_button.pack()
        self.master.mainloop()

    def show_var(self):
        print(self.var.get())

    @staticmethod
    def show_radioname(radio_name):
        print(radio_name)

Gui(Tk())
```